# android ssl certificate

Tags: android, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, code-signing-certificate

Assuming, my application need to access my web server using server certificate that is not supported by Nexus One (or other android devices), for example.

is it possible to 'embedded' the client certificate in the application? is this the same as signing the app with the client certificate?

Thanks

Comment: **Simple way to Create SSL certificate** https://stackoverflow.com/a/45344164/6050845

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is possible to embed the server certificate in the application.

Look at my [blog article](http://blog.antoine.li/index.php/2010/10/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/). I posted a detailed description how you can achieve this with creating your own keystore.

Comment: it would be great if you can post it again?

Comment: Unfortunately the webserver is down. But I posted the blog article on SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012497/accepting-a-certificate-for-https-on-android/3998257#3998257