# download image from server with https protocol in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accepting a certificate for HTTPs on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012497/accepting-a-certificate-for-https-on-android)

I need to download image from server with URL start with **https** to sdcard but it fire **javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificatejavax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate**.

I am able to download image if when URL start with http.

Comment: @Tom Dignan : That I didn't know , both were same question.