# Could not validate certificate signature?

Tags: android, https, x509certificate

I use the SSL Socket and Trustmanager from this side [Self signed SSL](http://blog.synyx.de/2010/06/android-and-self-signed-ssl-certificates/)

but i keep getting following error:

> 09-28 19:52:41.942: WARN/System.err(10101): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate signature.

What is wrong?
I already checked different posts on stackoverflow but i can`t seem to get it to work.

My code:

```
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();

// http scheme

schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));

// https scheme

schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", new EasySSLSocketFactory(), 443));
params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter(ConnManagerPNames.MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS, 1);
params.setParameter(ConnManagerPNames.MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE, new ConnPerRouteBean(1));
params.setParameter(HttpProtocolParams.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, "utf8");
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope("www.example.com", AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password"));
clientConnectionManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);
context = new BasicHttpContext();
context.setAttribute("http.auth.credentials-provider", credentialsProvider);

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(clientConnectionManager, params);

HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://www.example.com/web/restricted/form/formelement=512663");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(get, context);

Log.w("Response ","Status line : "+ response.toString());
```

Comment: You may also want to check the date and time settings on the phone. If the clocks are too far out of sync you can get similar errors to this.

Comment: If you use `Fuel` as a REST library, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460211/kotlin-library-that-can-do-https-connection-without-certificate-verification-li/54276837.

Answer (score 36):

As Michael Levy mentioned, the reason I was getting this exception is that I had left my Android Emulator open for a few days and the clock had gotten pretty far out of sync. Once I restarted the emulator, the exception went away.

Comment: I had a similar issue on a physical Galaxy Note device with no SIM. Interestingly, the built in browser worked fine. Once I updated the time sync settings to automatic, I no longer experienced any errors.

Comment: True, I was facing issue with the certificate handshake and had found that my device time was not properly set. It was set to somethings in past and ssl handshake failed.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE

I also got another error on API 16 emulator:

> routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
> (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741'.

Reading [1](https://medium.com/@krisnavneet/how-to-solve-sslhandshakeexception-in-android-ssl23-get-server-hello-tlsv1-alert-protocol-13b457c724ef) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539513/how-to-enable-tlsv1-3-for-okhttp-3-12-x-on-android-8-9), I changed code so:

```
val okHttpClient = getOkHttpBuilder().build()

private fun getOkHttpBuilder(): OkHttpClient.Builder {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Security.insertProviderAt(Conscrypt.newProvider(), 1)
    }
    return OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
}

// build.gradle:
implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.5.1'
```

But the [library](https://github.com/google/conscrypt) adds 3.4 Mb to apk.

I also removed these lines from `MyApplication`:

```
try {
    ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(applicationContext)
    val sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2")
    sslContext.init(null, null, null)
    sslContext.createSSLEngine()
} catch (e: GooglePlayServicesRepairableException) {
    Timber.e(e.stackTraceToString())
    // Prompt the user to install/update/enable Google Play services.
    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().showErrorNotification(this, e.connectionStatusCode)
} catch (e: GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException) {
    Timber.e(e.stackTraceToString())
    // Prompt the user to install/update/enable Google Play services.
    // GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().showErrorNotification(this, e.errorCode)
} catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
    Timber.e(e.stackTraceToString())
} catch (e: KeyManagementException) {
    Timber.e(e.stackTraceToString())
}
```

=== Old answer ===

In my case a following error raised on Android 4 and 5:

> Caused by:
> com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException:
> Could not validate certificate: Certificate expired at Sat May 30
> 10:48:38 GMT+00:00 2020 (compared to Thu Aug 13 11:47:00 GMT+00:00
> 2020)
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException:
> Certificate expired at Sat May 30 10:48:38 GMT+00:00 2020 (compared to
> Thu Aug 13 11:47:00 GMT+00:00 2020)

The server has certificate error (probably expired).

For `Retrofit` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60507560/2914140. If you use `Fuel` as a REST library, see [kotlin library that can do httpS connection without certificate verification (like curl --insecure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460211/kotlin-library-that-can-do-https-connection-without-certificate-verification-li/54276837).

You can trust all certificates, but it's dangerous.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate
import javax.net.ssl.*
import javax.security.cert.CertificateException

companion object {

    private val gson: Gson
    private val retrofit: Retrofit

    init {

        val okHttpClient = getOkHttpBuilder().build()

        gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()

        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build()
    }

    private fun getOkHttpBuilder(): OkHttpClient.Builder =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        } else {
            getUnsafeOkHttpClient()
        }

    private fun getUnsafeOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient.Builder =
        try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            val trustAllCerts: Array<TrustManager> = arrayOf(
                object : X509TrustManager {
                    @Throws(CertificateException::class)
                    override fun checkClientTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate?>?,
                                                    authType: String?) = Unit

                    @Throws(CertificateException::class)
                    override fun checkServerTrusted(chain: Array<X509Certificate?>?,
                                                    authType: String?) = Unit

                    override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate> = arrayOf()
                }
            )
            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            val sslContext: SSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, SecureRandom())
            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            val sslSocketFactory: SSLSocketFactory = sslContext.socketFactory
            val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory,
                trustAllCerts[0] as X509TrustManager)
            builder.hostnameVerifier { _, _ -> true }
            builder
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/60507560/2914140 for Android version check and `Glide` connection.

Comment: I have exactly the same error on Crashlytics for Android 4 and 5, but I'm still quite puzzled on why it happens and why only on these 2 OS.

Comment: @VGM, thanks! As I understood after months of appearing-disappearing problems with a certificate, in Android 4 and 5 it cannot establish connection via new protocols by default. So, we need to enable SSL, TLS 1.2, 1.3. You know, it was difficult for me, so I just removed trusting. I don't know whether it works on all old devices, but in emulators and some devices removing trusting works.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably server returned certificate chain with authorities you do not trust. 
(means: authority certificates are not known to your device as trusted)
Solution:  carefully examine certificates  coming from HTTPS  website,  and add respective authorities to your truststore - but this part seems to be tricky

( here some explanations :
http://groups.google.com/group/android-security-discuss/browse_thread/thread/0bf726de4f5275a3/391b900631d7f358 )

Comment: Hi Konstantin,
Thx for the reply but i think i have to login to this site another way, this is too complicated.
The site i want to login has a login form which can be submitted through HTTP, the login is then authenticated and redirects through SSL to the page i want.
I think a HTTP Post with preserved cookies from a HTTPGet should do it or?

Comment: You did not make it that far - you never get HTTPS connection.  You may succeed by submiting HTTP form,  but redirect over SSH will not work unless you sort certificate problem -  It's your side which does not trust the server.   Funny thing is, that some servers are buggy and just can not verify signatures of clients (notably JBoss had this bug)

Answer (score 1):

Check the time of your device, correct it and then check again.

Answer (score 0):

BTW，we could re-produce this error easily -- just change the date of the phone to several years later.

NOTE: the error might be a little difference in different phone. Some might show that the certificate has expired.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like wrong date/time of the device

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).