# SSLHandshakeException: Certificate Exception using HttpURLConnetion with Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, web-services, security, ssl-certificate, httpurlconnection

I am struggling with a strange issue, while using **HttpURLConnection** for webservice api call in Android. I am getting below exception **ONLY with Android version 4.2.2**. It is working fine in Android 4.0.3, 4.3 and 4.4 and above.
I am using below code for service api call.

```
HttpURLConnection mConn = (HttpURLConnection)mUrl.openConnection();
mConn.addRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
mConn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
mConn.setReadTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
mConn.setUseCaches(true);
mConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
String param = Utils.appendQueryParams(null,this.stringparams);
mConn.setDoInput(true);
mConn.setDoOutput(true);
mConn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(param.getBytes().length);
mConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
mConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
mConn.connect();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(mConn.getOutputStream());
out.print(param);
out.close();
```

Here is the Exception (ONLY in Android SDK version 4.2.2)

```
08-18 11:43:22.663  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: IssuerName(CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US) does not match SubjectName(CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2, OU=https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US) of signing certificate.
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:381)
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:165)
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at com.halomem.android.utils.ServiceCall.executeRequest(ServiceCall.java:86)
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at com.halomem.android.impl.Session$1.run(Session.java:161)
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: IssuerName(CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US) does not match SubjectName(CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2, OU=https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US) of signing certificate.
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:296)
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:197)
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:597)
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:378)
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ ... 9 more
08-18 11:43:22.833  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ Caused by: com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: IssuerName(CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US) does not match SubjectName(CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2, OU=https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, O="GoDaddy.com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, ST=Arizona, C=US) of signing certificate.
08-18 11:43:22.843  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.RFC3280CertPathUtilities.processCertA(RFC3280CertPathUtilities.java:1525)
08-18 11:43:22.843  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:305)
08-18 11:43:22.843  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at com.sec.android.security.pkix.SecCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(SecCertPathValidatorSpi.java:99)
08-18 11:43:22.843  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:190)
08-18 11:43:22.843  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:283)
08-18 11:43:22.843  26427-26485/com.abc.xyz W/System.err﹕ ... 13 more
```

Please suggest in this regard.

Thanks
Himanshu.

Comment: Dear all anyone tried this?

Comment: See this answer maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115101/apache-httpclient-on-android-producing-certpathvalidatorexception-issuername

Comment: If it's version specific, it might be a bug in 4.2.2 or specific to the device you are testing with. Did you try with the emulator or a Nexus device? The error itself suggests that the certificate the server is return is not properly signed, or perhaps the server is misconfigured. How does the server certificate look like?

Comment: Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588082/could-not-validate-certificate-signature

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys, but in my scenario, i am not using HttpClient.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov: If it is a version specific issue then, is there any solution for this? I have tried this all types of devices and emulator with version 4.2.2. but no luck. It is working fine with other version devices or emulator.

Comment: Certificates out of order seems the most plausible cause, check the link in the second comment. Also use openssl to check how your server returns certificates.

Comment: Got the same issue on serval 4.2.2 and 4.2.1 devices. It can be sure that it is the system issue. I have to trust certificates manually on those machines.

Answer (score 10):

**Important note**

> Check your device time is correct or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like authority of certificate is not trusted on your device. Checkout this post: [Could not validate certificate signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588082/could-not-validate-certificate-signature)