# How to enable TLSv1.3 for OkHttp 3.12.x on Android 8/9?

Tags: android, okhttp, tls1.3

I'm using OkHttp 3.12.2 on Android 9 (Pixel 2 device) and try to connect to an nginx 1.14.0 running with OpenSSL 1.1.1. The nginx is capable of TLSv1.3, I verified this with Firefox 66.0.2 on Ubuntu 18.04, Chrome 73.0 on Android 9 and ChromeOS 72.0.

However, **OkHttp always negotiates TLSv1.2**. I also tried to set a RESTRICTED_TLS ConnectionSpec, but it didn't help.

I did not find a specific instruction on how to get TLSv1.3 working on Android. I know that only Android 8 and 9 support TLSv1.3 out of the box; I'm fine for now with that restriction.

My experience from earlier TLS migrations is that I don't have to do anything except updating all involved components.

Comment: What server are you hitting? Does it have TLSv1.3?

Comment: @JesseWilson It's an TLSv1.3-capable nginx 1.14.0/OpenSSL 1.1.1 installation. Firefox on Ubuntu and Chrome on Android both connect via TLSv1.3.

Answer (score 34):

As shown in official [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket), 
TLSv1.3 is supported from Android 10(Api Level 29) on wards. So to support TLSv1.3 in previous versions we can integrate the [conscrypt](https://github.com/google/conscrypt) library. Conscrypt security provider includes a public API for TLS functionality. For that we have to add the dependency,

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.2.1'
}
```

Here also we need OkHttp client as it supports conscrypt.

As documented in [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/),

> OkHttp uses your platform’s built-in TLS implementation. On Java
>   platforms OkHttp also supports Conscrypt, which integrates BoringSSL
>   with Java. OkHttp will use Conscrypt if it is the first security
>   provider.

After adding conscrypt dependency, in application class we just have to mention,

```
Security.insertProviderAt(Conscrypt.newProvider(), 1);
```

This can be helpful to provide support and enable TLS 1.3 in older android version (Api level <29).

Comment: Correct me if I was wrong, code from OkHttp `Platform.kt` suggests otherwise. It will first match android and then Conscrypt. `ConscryptPlatform` instance will not be returned from method `Platform.Companion.findPlatform` on android devices.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is likely, that the client or the certificate might not support TLS 1.3 in all situations - and then will fall back. Try running [SSL test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) to verify that (it also performs checks for mobile clients, which might negotiate differently). Upgrading OhHttp to `3.13` or `3.14` (soon) might also be an option; here's the [change log](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/TLS-Configuration-History). even if Android should support it, the client needs to be configured, as well:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectionSpecs(Arrays.asList(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS))
    .build();
```

Possible values there are: `RESTRICTED_TLS`, `MODERN_TLS` and (backwards) `COMPATIBLE_TLS`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I already ran the SSL test and [it passes](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=schildbach.de&latest) the TLSv1.3 tests. All TLSv1.3 cipher suites are supported: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 and TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256.

Comment: @AndreasSchildbach (updating and/or) explicitly setting `MODERN_TLS` or `RESTRICTED_TLS` still might result in a different protocol negotiation. no clue what the default value is.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't update to OkHttp 3.13 and beyond because Square hiked the requirements too far for me (using Java 8 language features require a recent Android Gradle plugin which breaks deterministic builds due to a long-standing bug). But OkHttp 3.12.x is receiving backports they say.

Comment: As I mentioned in the description, I set the client to RESTRICTED_TLS. Default is MODERN_TLS afaik, which also doesn't work.

Comment: @AndreasSchildbach there was a bug filed against `javax.net.ssl`: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8202625 & https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8202625 make sure the version you are using is not affected by that. testing with a [TLS 1.3 only client](https://blog.gypsyengineer.com/en/security/an-example-of-tls-13-client-and-server-on-java.html) might also help to rectify the culprit.

Comment: I suddenly have the feeling Android 9 doesn't support TLSv1.3 yet, despite me remembering reading about it 2 years ago. I just tried running `SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3");` but got `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLSv1.3 SSLContext not available`. And the changelog for Android Q (unreleased) does [mention it](https://developer.android.com/preview/features#tls-1.3) like a new feature.

Comment: Yep, you need Q. https://twitter.com/jessewilson/status/1106035125878513664