# Exception in http url connection setup

Tags: android

I have encountered an exception on connection.connect().I have attached the output of my logcat.
There is mentioned about Run time exception.I have tried to run this service on thread but still the exception is occuring.
I don't know why it is caused. Please inform Why this exception has occurred and How can I fix it.

Code:

```
public class TimeZoneDownloadingService extends Service {

    private IBinder mBinder  = new myBinder();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        showMessage("Service Started");


    }
    private void showMessage(String message)
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        showMessage("StartCommand");
        //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                StartDownloadTimezone();
            }
        });
        //thread.start();

        thread.start();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        showMessage(" on Bind");
        return mBinder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        stopSelf();
    }
    public class myBinder extends Binder {

        TimeZoneDownloadingService getService()
        {
            return TimeZoneDownloadingService.this;
        }

    }
    public void StartDownloadTimezone()  {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStream  stream = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL("https://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/list-time-zone?key=P8B5V3KL22GA&format=json&country=US");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.connect();

            stream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = " ";
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            parse(buffer);
            showMessage("URL connection successful");


        }catch(Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    private void parse(StringBuffer buff)
    {
        showMessage("Parsing");
    }


}
```

Logcat:

```
06-12 21:40:42.398 16115-16115/? E/Zygote: v2
06-12 21:40:42.398 16115-16115/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10080
06-12 21:40:42.398 16115-16115/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
06-12 21:40:42.398 16115-16115/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-J500H_5.1.1 ver=48
06-12 21:40:42.398 16115-16115/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [1] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-J500H_5.1.1_0048
06-12 21:40:42.398 16115-16115/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
06-12 21:40:42.398 16115-16115/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
06-12 21:40:42.418 16115-16115/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: in addTimaSignatureService
06-12 21:40:42.418 16115-16115/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
06-12 21:40:42.418 16115-16115/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKesytore provider
06-12 21:40:42.448 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: com.example.worldclocktest for user  0
06-12 21:40:42.458 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
06-12 21:40:42.458 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
06-12 21:40:42.458 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
06-12 21:40:42.458 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap com.example.worldclocktest
06-12 21:40:42.468 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest I/InjectionManager: Constructor com.example.worldclocktest, Feature store :{}
06-12 21:40:42.468 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
06-12 21:40:42.478 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: com.example.worldclocktest for user  0
06-12 21:40:42.478 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: com.example.worldclocktest for user  0
06-12 21:40:42.538 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: com.example.worldclocktest for user  0
06-12 21:40:42.538 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: com.example.worldclocktest for user  0
06-12 21:40:42.538 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest D/DisplayManager: DisplayManager()
06-12 21:40:42.548 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-12 21:40:42.578 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
06-12 21:40:42.578 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
06-12 21:40:42.608 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
06-12 21:40:42.608 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
06-12 21:40:42.868 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
06-12 21:40:42.868 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.example.worldclocktest.MainActivity isFragment :false
06-12 21:40:42.908 16115-16131/com.example.worldclocktest D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
06-12 21:40:42.938 16115-16132/com.example.worldclocktest I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-12 21:40:42.938 16115-16132/com.example.worldclocktest I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
06-12 21:40:42.938 16115-16132/com.example.worldclocktest I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-6283-58592290: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
06-12 21:40:42.938 16115-16132/com.example.worldclocktest I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Thread-6283-58592290: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is false
06-12 21:40:42.938 16115-16132/com.example.worldclocktest I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
06-12 21:40:42.948 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
06-12 21:40:42.948 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
06-12 21:40:42.978 16115-16131/com.example.worldclocktest I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3_RB1.05.01.00.032.018_msm8916_32_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3_RB1.05.01.00.032.018__release_AU (I856e09677e)
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
    Build Date: 05/03/15 Sun
    Local Branch: 
    Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.1.3_RB1.05.01.00.032.018
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
06-12 21:40:42.978 16115-16131/com.example.worldclocktest I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-12 21:40:42.998 16115-16131/com.example.worldclocktest D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
06-12 21:40:43.008 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-12 21:40:43.048 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest I/InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :com.example.worldclocktest.MainActivity
06-12 21:40:43.048 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest I/InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :com.example.worldclocktest.MainActivity
06-12 21:40:43.118 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-12 21:40:43.128 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@329f0535 time:88098473
06-12 21:40:44.498 16115-16132/com.example.worldclocktest W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
06-12 21:40:44.498 16115-16132/com.example.worldclocktest W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
06-12 21:40:44.498 16115-16132/com.example.worldclocktest W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
06-12 21:40:44.498 16115-16132/com.example.worldclocktest W/System.err:     at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:569)
06-12 21:40:44.498 16115-16132/com.example.worldclocktest W/System.err:     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:129)
06-12 21:40:44.498 16115-16132/com.example.worldclocktest W/System.err:     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:427)
06-12 21:40:44.498 16115-16132/com.example.worldclocktest W/System.err:     at com.example.worldclocktest.TimeZoneDownloadingService.showMessage(TimeZoneDownloadingService.java:31)
06-12 21:40:44.498 16115-16132/com.example.worldclocktest W/System.err:     at com.example.worldclocktest.TimeZoneDownloadingService.parse(TimeZoneDownloadingService.java:103)
06-12 21:40:44.498 16115-16132/com.example.worldclocktest W/System.err:     at com.example.worldclocktest.TimeZoneDownloadingService.StartDownloadTimezone(TimeZoneDownloadingService.java:91)
06-12 21:40:44.498 16115-16132/com.example.worldclocktest W/System.err:     at com.example.worldclocktest.TimeZoneDownloadingService$1.run(TimeZoneDownloadingService.java:41)
06-12 21:40:44.498 16115-16132/com.example.worldclocktest W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-12 21:40:49.868 16115-16115/com.example.worldclocktest D/DisplayManager: DisplayManager()
```

```
06-12 22:33:16.304 19546-19573/com.example.worldclocktest W/System.err: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb89447a0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
```

Comment: Remove your `Toast`. Do something else, such as a `Log` call to log a message to Logcat.

Comment: Now I am getting an handler exception

Comment: Try commenting the line `parse(buffer);` and [change your TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61559588/10534012).