# How to enable TLSv1.3 for HttpURLConnection on Android 8/9?

Tags: java, android-studio, http, ssl

I am making an application in Android Studio where I make an HTTP request with HttpURLConnection to a server. That server is configured with TLS v1.3 and only works fine with Android 10.

In Android 8 and 9 I get this error: Handsake failed.

Does this have a solution? How can I get TLS 1.3 to work on Android 8 and 9?

This is my code :

```
            String query = "https://....";
            token ="...."
            URL url = new URL(query);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);

            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            os.close();
    
       
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            String result = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
            JsonObject jobj = new Gson().fromJson(result, JsonObject.class);
```

Comment: Hi Alberto! Always make sure you provide detailed information about the error such as images or the code itself so the community can help you out.

Comment: @AugustoPohl done!

Comment: TLS 1.3 is only supported in the native TLS stack since Android 10. But see [How to enable TLSv1.3 for OkHttp 3.12.x on Android 8/9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539513/how-to-enable-tlsv1-3-for-okhttp-3-12-x-on-android-8-9) for alternatives.