# How integrate the new conscrypt library to Android and use it by default

Tags: android, google-conscrypt

In android, if i get `(SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()` i get the inner socket factory with this class `com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl`.

After adding this [dependency](https://github.com/google/conscrypt)

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.2.1'
}
```

I want to get `(SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()` the factory from new lib (`org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl`), but still geting the inner `com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl`.
What is the integration algorithm for the new SocketFactory ?

Comment: You should explain why you are using `google-conscrypt`. My guess is TLS 1.3, see: [How to enable TLSv1.3 for OkHttp 3.12.x on Android 8/9?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55539513/295004)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the Conscrypt provider as first security provider, otherwise it will not be loaded:

```java
Security.insertProviderAt(Conscrypt.newProvider(), 1);
```

Setting it as first provider will prevent Android from using the default one.