# Retrofit2 / OkHttpClient: how to enable and configure SNI

Tags: java, retrofit2, okhttp, sni

I'm using Retrofit2 (that uses OkHttpClient) to make REST requests to the server.
I'm using TLSv1.3 protocol.

How can I enable and configure SNI (Server Name Indication) for my client?

Comment: I think your question already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539513/how-to-enable-tlsv1-3-for-okhttp-3-12-x-on-android-8-9)

Comment: based on the discussion [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4324), SNI is enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

It's enabled automatically using the hostname in the URL.

Comment: Do we have any control on it? Let's assume that tomorrow I'll need to disable it, test it, overwrite something,.... Where is entry point? In ConnectionSpec? SslContext?

Comment: It's all internal. If you want to do domain fronting, you can change the URL no you're connecting to but set something else in the `Host` HTTP header.