# Android java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLSv1.3 SSLContext not available

Tags: java, android

I want to change TLS version from 1.2 to 1.3 but I keep getting:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: TLSv1.3 SSLContext not available
```

Enabling 1.3

```
((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.3"});
```

Error:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3");
```

Java version: 1.8.0_332

Thank you in advance!

Comment: TLSv1.3 is supported from Android 10 (API Level 29) onwards, what API are you using?

Comment: Had lower Android version, managed to solve the problem by adding conscript. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55539513/how-to-enable-tlsv1-3-for-okhttp-3-12-x-on-android-8-9)