# Using openssl to get the certificate from a server

Tags: linux, security, certificate, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to get the certificate of a remote server, which I can then use to add to my keystore and use within my Java application.

A senior dev (who is on holidays :( ) informed me I can run this:

```
openssl s_client -connect host.host:9999
```

to get a raw certificate dumped out, which I can then copy and export. I receive the following output:

```
depth=1 /C=NZ/ST=Test State or Province/O=Organization Name/OU=Organizational Unit Name/CN=Test CA
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
23177:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1086:SSL alert number 40
23177:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:
```

I have also tried it with this option:

```
-showcerts
```

and this one (running on Debian mind you):

```
-CApath /etc/ssl/certs/
```

But I get the same error.

[This source](http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/personal.shtml) says I can use that CApath flag but it doesn't seem to help. I tried multiple paths to no avail.

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It turns out there is more complexity here: I needed to provide many more details to get this rolling. I think its something to do with the fact that its a connection that needs client authentication, and the hankshake needed more info to continue to the stage where the certificates were dumped.

Here is my working command:

```
openssl s_client -connect host:port -key our_private_key.pem -showcerts \
                 -cert our_server-signed_cert.pem
```

Hopefully this is a nudge in the right direction for anyone who could do with some more info.

Comment: I am sorry, but your answer doesn't make much sense. You needed to pass the certificate to the server in order to get the certificate?

Comment: Yep. Client authentication AFAIK.

Comment: It turns out '-prexit' will return that data as well. E.g.; openssl s_client -connect host:port -prexit

Answer (score 675):

## With SNI

If the remote server is using SNI (that is, sharing multiple SSL hosts on a single IP address) you will need to send the correct hostname in order to get the right certificate.

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername www.example.com -connect www.example.com:443 </dev/null
```

*If you get an error similar to `xxx:error:xxx:BIO routines:BIO_lookup_ex:system lib:crypto/bio/bio_addr.c:758:nodename nor servname provided, or not known connect:errno=0`, execute the same command without `www` as the domain may not support it.*

*You may also get `Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported` behind a corporate firewall in which  case, a temporary (but dangerous) workaround is the `-legacy_renegotiation` parameter that can be added to the above command.*

## Without SNI

If the remote server is not using SNI, then you can skip `-servername` parameter:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.example.com:443 </dev/null
```

To view the full details of a site's cert you can use this chain of commands as well:

```
$ echo | \
    openssl s_client -servername www.example.com -connect www.example.com:443 2>/dev/null | \
    openssl x509 -text
```

Comment: Hmm. I still get the same error when trying that command. I noticed my Openssl version is 'OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007'. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Useful: `echo "" | openssl s_client -connect server:port -prexit 2>/dev/null | sed -n -e '/BEGIN\ CERTIFICATE/,/END\ CERTIFICATE/ p'` http://stackoverflow.com/a/12918442/843000

Comment: Alternative useful script, from [madboa.com](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/):
`echo | openssl s_client -connect server:port 2>&1 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > cert.pem`

Comment: To make this a bit more concise, you can replace the `sed` with `openssl x509`, and read it in using a sub-shell: `openssl x509 -in <(openssl s_client -connect server:port -prexit 2>/dev/null)`

Comment: Also `echo | openssl s_client -connect google.com:443  2>/dev/null | openssl x509`

Comment: `echo | openssl s_client -servername example.com -connect example.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text` to get human readable output as well. Also as an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35442314/289064).

Comment: If you get a `write:errno=54` you may be communicating with a TLS1.2 only server using an older version of openssl (you need 1.0.1 or newer for TLS1.2).  This happened to me on macOS 10.12

Comment: And if it is a Mailserver (SMTP) using starttls you want to get the certificate from, use: `openssl s_client -connect server:port -starttls smtp`

Comment: Since OpenSSL 1.1.1, SNI is enabled by default: "If -servername is not provided, the TLS SNI extension will be populated with the name given to -connect if it follows a DNS name format."

Comment: As per @Alastair McCormack comment, from version 1.1.1 and up SNI is enabled by default. You need to pass the `-noservername` flag to disable it

Comment: @mbrownnyc `-prexit` will print the certificate twice in the screen. Why is this flag needed?

Comment: In my corporate environment these commands just hang and don't terminate. The reason  is probably that we use a proxy, and commands like `curl` honor that, but `openssl` does not and gets blocked.

Comment: In my case the -showcerts option made the difference because I need to validate the whole chain

Comment: Servers can return the certs in the CA chain in addition to the server cert. That will cause the piping through "openssl x509 -text" to show only the first cert returned.

Answer (score 121):

A one-liner to extract the certificate from a remote server in PEM format, this time using `sed`:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 2>/dev/null </dev/null |  sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'
```

Comment: This one is almost perfect to extract the certificate, just missing the `-servername` option, don't know why, but I had to use it to get the full certificate.

Comment: -servername is required for server name indication (SNI).  Web searching can expand on the rest.

Answer (score 80):

While I agree with Ari's answer (and upvoted it :), I needed to do an extra step to get it to work with Java on Windows (where it needed to be deployed):

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.example.com:443 < /dev/null | openssl x509 -outform DER > derp.der
```

Before adding the `openssl x509 -outform DER` conversion, I was getting an error from keytool on Windows complaining about the certificate's format.  Importing the .der file worked fine.

Comment: Odd. I've been using PEM certificates with keytool on Windows since Java 6 and never faced an issue.

Answer (score 40):

The easiest command line for this, which includes the PEM output to add it to the keystore, as well as a human readable output and also supports SNI, which is important if you are working with an HTTP server is:

```
openssl s_client -servername example.com -connect example.com:443 \
    </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text
```

The *-servername* option is to enable SNI support and the *openssl x509 -text* prints the certificate in human readable format.

Comment: You may add to your -servername your subdomain, for instance ws.example.com instead of example.com (apply this to the -connect parameter too).

Comment: Servers can return the certs in the CA chain in addition to the server cert. That will cause the piping through "openssl x509 -text" to show only the first cert returned.

Answer (score 30):

To get the certificate of remote server you can use `openssl` tool and you can find it between `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` and `END CERTIFICATE` which you need to copy and paste into your certificate file (CRT).

Here is the command demonstrating it:

```
ex +'/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,/END CERTIFICATE/p' <(echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443) -scq > file.crt
```

To return all certificates from the chain, just add `g` (global) like:

```
ex +'g/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,/END CERTIFICATE/p' <(echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443) -scq
```

Then you can simply import your certificate file (`file.crt`) into your keychain and make it trusted, so Java shouldn't complain.

On OS X you can double-click on the file or drag and drop in your Keychain Access, so it'll appear in login/Certificates. Then double-click on the imported certificated and make it *Always Trust for SSL*.

On CentOS 5 you can append them into `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` file (and run: `sudo update-ca-trust force-enable`), or in CentOS 6 copy them into `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` and run `sudo update-ca-trust extract`.

In Ubuntu, copy them into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and run `sudo update-ca-certificates`.

Answer (score 13):

```
HOST=gmail-pop.l.google.com
PORT=995

openssl s_client -servername $HOST -connect $HOST:$PORT < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform pem
```

Comment: Servers can return the certs in the CA chain in addition to the server cert. That will cause the piping through "openssl x509 -outform pem" to show only the first cert returned.

Answer (score 10):

to print only the certificate chain and not the server's certificate:

```
# MYHOST=myhost.com
# MYPORT=443
# openssl s_client -connect ${MYHOST}:${MYPORT} -showcerts 2>/dev/null </dev/null | awk '/^.*'"${MYHOST}"'/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/{next;}/-----BEGIN/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/{print}'
```

to update CA trust on CentOS/RHEL 6/7 :

```
# update-ca-trust enable
# openssl s_client -connect ${MYHOST}:${MYPORT} -showcerts 2>/dev/null </dev/null | awk '/^.*'"${MYHOST}"'/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/{next;}/-----BEGIN/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/{print}' >/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/myca.cert
# update-ca-trust extract
```

on CentOS/RHEL 5:

```
# openssl s_client -connect ${MYHOST}:${MYPORT} -showcerts 2>/dev/null </dev/null | awk '/^.*'"${MYHOST}"'/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/{next;}/-----BEGIN/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/{print}' >>/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed on CentOS7. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I also had the same challenge and next to that I discovered that openssl doesn't return the root ca. I have built an alternative for specifically for this purpose which might be useful for other developers, see here: [GitHub - Certificate ripper](https://github.com/Hakky54/certificate-ripper)

**Usage**

- Printing to the console

```
crip print -u=https://stackoverflow.com/ --format=pem
```

- Exporting to a pkcs12 truststore

```
crip export p12 -u=https://stackoverflow.com/
```

The `p12` option can be replaced for `jks`, `pem` or `der` if you want a different output.

Comment: Pretty useful tool ! any way we can specify the target file for the export ? I'm thinking path and format. Thanks

Comment: I was just about to fork and add that option, but I see that you already added it - thank you so much ! :)

Comment: Yes I have added it and published it today. Thank you for mentioning this idea, it was good to have this option in the app

Comment: One small issue I noticed, the published source code is not the latest one ^^

Comment: I have republished it, hopefully it is now correct :) Can you retry?

Comment: There is another `crip` utility in debian packages, so not to be confused.

Answer (score 7):

If your server is an email server (MS Exchange or Zimbra) maybe you need to add the `starttls` and `smtp` flags:

`openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect HOST_EMAIL:SECURE_PORT 2>/dev/null </dev/null |  sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > CERTIFICATE_NAME.pem`

Where,

- **HOST_EMAIL** is the server domain, for example, mail-server.com.
- **SECURE_PORT** is the communication port, for example, 587 or 465
- **CERTIFICATE_NAME** output's filename (BASE 64/PEM Format)

Answer (score 5):

You can get and store the server root certificate using next bash script:

```
CERTS=$(echo -n | openssl s_client -connect $HOST_NAME:$PORT -showcerts | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p')
echo "$CERTS" | awk -v RS="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" 'NR > 1 { printf RS $0 > "'$SERVER_ROOT_CERTIFICATE'"; close("'$SERVER_ROOT_CERTIFICATE'") }'
```

Just overwrite required variables.

Answer (score 5):

There are already good answers. But it's worth to mention the latest curl version (>7.88.0) will do this simple for you...

```
curl https://example.com -w "%{certs}" -o /dev/null > cacert.pem
```

Add `--insecure` if the server uses self signed certificate. And add `--head` to avoid the response body.

See availability and requirements here:
[cURL -w certs feature](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2022/12/28/curl-w-certs/)

Comment: Just for clarity, curl 7.88 isn't actually out yet at the time of writing - due to be released Feb 2023.

Answer (score 4):

Start the client:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts stackoverflow.com:443
```

Quit by stopping STDIN (CTRL+D), or terminate the process (CTRL+C).

To disable input and force the client to quit after displaying the certificates:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts stackoverflow.com:443 < /dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of others like me who tried to follow the good advice here when accessing [AWS CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) but failed, the trick is to add `-servername domain.name..`.

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/780450/8972

Answer (score 1):

I was in case where two certificates was output from aboves commands; so i get to this point to extract only the 2nd part : **the server certificate**

Sorry for the long command:

```
openssl s_client -servername token.actions.githubusercontent.com -showcerts -connect token.actions.githubusercontent.com:443 2>/dev/null </dev/null | awk '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/ && c++,/END CERTIFICATE/'
```