# awk show lines between two matches

Tags: regex, xml, awk, sed, grep

I want to extract lines from file between `<div class="AA">`  and `<div class="clear"></div>`.

regex with `sed` and `grep` are welcome as well.

## Update

Here is part of my huge XML file:

```
RUBBISH
RUBBISH
.
.
.
    <div class="span9">
          <div class="results-count">AAA</div>
    <div class="AA">
      <div class="A"><a href="/TEST">BBB</a>
      </div>
      <div class="BB"><span>CCC</span><br/><a href="/TEST1" class="B">DDD</a>
        <div></div><span>EEE</span><br/><img src="TEST2" title="C"/><a href="/TEST3" class="D">FFF</a>,
    <a href="/TEST4" class="E">GGG</a>
        <div class="clear"></div><a href="/TEST5" class="details">Details</a>
      </div>
      <pre>HHH</pre>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    .
    .
    .
    <div class="span9">
          <div class="results-count">AAA</div>
    <div class="AA">
      <div class="A"><a href="/TEST">BBB</a>
      </div>
      <div class="BB"><span>CCC</span><br/><a href="/TEST1" class="B">DDD</a>
        <div></div><span>EEE</span><br/><img src="TEST2" title="C"/><a href="/TEST3" class="D">FFF</a>,
    <a href="/TEST4" class="E">GGG</a>
        <div class="clear"></div><a href="/TEST5" class="details">Details</a>
      </div>
      <pre>HHH</pre>
      <div class="clear"></div>


RUBBISH
RUBBISH


    <div class="span9">
          <div class="results-count">AAA</div>
    <div class="AA">
      <div class="A"><a href="/TEST">BBB</a>
      </div>
      <div class="BB"><span>CCC</span><br/><a href="/TEST1" class="B">DDD</a>
        <div></div><span>EEE</span><br/><img src="TEST2" title="C"/><a href="/TEST3" class="D">FFF</a>,
    <a href="/TEST4" class="E">GGG</a>
        <div class="clear"></div><a href="/TEST5" class="details">Details</a>
      </div>
      <pre>HHH</pre>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: you can also check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918292/grep-access-multiple-lines-find-all-words-between-two-patterns

Comment: @Mortez provide a sample file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '/<div class="clear"><\/div>/{p=0} p{print} /<div class="results-count">/{p=1}'
```

Comment: Thank you... I have multiple of this pattern in my huge xml file... What should I do for that?

Comment: What you should do is describe your problem in more detail. My code will work for multiple blocks, but it may not do what you want, so... what do you want that this code is not already doing?

Comment: Please check the update... I have many of this block and also some extra xml tags. But I want just this block

Comment: And again, having looked at the sample data, I still fail to see what you need that the snippet in my answer does not address. Please describe the difference between your expectations and the output of my code. You keep saying you have "multiple of this pattern in my huge xml file"; my code handles multiple occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Through grep,

```
$ grep -ozP '(?s)(?:\n|^)\s*<div class="results-count">[^\n]*\n\K.*?(?=\n\s*<div class="clear"></div>)' file
<div class="AA">
  <div class="A"><a href="/TEST">BBB</a>
  </div>
  <div class="BB"><span>CCC</span><br/><a href="/TEST1" class="B">DDD</a>
    <div></div><span>EEE</span><br/><img src="TEST2" title="C"/><a href="/TEST3" class="D">FFF</a>,
<a href="/TEST4" class="E">GGG</a>
```

[ReGex DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sG4iR3/1)