# how to get pem file from a server work for wireshark

Tags: ssl, encryption, wireshark

for example: 202.127.168.21:443

tried the command

```
    openssl s_client -connect server:port 2>&1 | sed -ne "/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p" > cert.pem
```

from [Using openssl to get the certificate from a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885785/using-openssl-to-get-the-certificate-from-a-server)

debug.txt

```
    Wireshark SSL debug log 

    ssl_load_key: can't import pem data: Base64 unexpected header error.

    dissect_ssl enter frame #4 (first time)
    ssl_session_init: initializing ptr 05EA6D14 size 592
      conversation = 05EA68F0, ssl_session = 05EA6D14
      record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 240
    dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
    decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 235, ssl state 0x00
    association_find: TCP port 3204 found 00000000
    packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
    decrypt_ssl3_record: using client decoder
    decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
    dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 1 offset 5 length 231 bytes, remaining 240 
    packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
    ssl_find_private_key server 202.127.168.21:443
    ssl_find_private_key can't find private key for this server! Try it again with universal port 0
    ssl_find_private_key can't find private key for this server (universal port)! Try it again with universal address 0.0.0.0
    ssl_find_private_key can't find any private key!
    dissect_ssl3_hnd_hello_common found CLIENT RANDOM -> state 0x01

    dissect_ssl enter frame #6 (first time)
      conversation = 05EA68F0, ssl_session = 05EA6D14
      record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 86
    dissect_ssl3_record found version 0x0303(TLS 1.2) -> state 0x11
    dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
    decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 81, ssl state 0x11
    packet_from_server: is from server - TRUE
    decrypt_ssl3_record: using server decoder
    decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
    dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 2 offset 5 length 77 bytes, remaining 86 
    dissect_ssl3_hnd_hello_common found SERVER RANDOM -> state 0x13
    ssl_restore_session can't find stored session
    trying to use SSL keylog in 
    failed to open SSL keylog
      cannot find master secret in keylog file either
    dissect_ssl3_hnd_srv_hello found CIPHER 0x0005 -> state 0x17
    dissect_ssl3_hnd_srv_hello trying to generate keys
    ssl_generate_keyring_material not enough data to generate key (0x17 required 0x37 or 0x57)
    dissect_ssl3_hnd_srv_hello can't generate keyring material

    dissect_ssl enter frame #7 (first time)
      conversation = 05EA68F0, ssl_session = 05EA6D14
      record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 6
    dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 20 Change Cipher Spec
    dissect_ssl3_change_cipher_spec
    packet_from_server: is from server - TRUE
    ssl_change_cipher SERVER

    dissect_ssl enter frame #9 (first time)
      conversation = 05EA68F0, ssl_session = 05EA6D14
      record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 41
    dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
    decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 36, ssl state 0x17
    packet_from_server: is from server - TRUE
    decrypt_ssl3_record: using server decoder
    decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
    dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 203 offset 5 length 9339809 bytes, remaining 41 

    dissect_ssl enter frame #10 (first time)
      conversation = 05EA68F0, ssl_session = 05EA6D14
      record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 47
    dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 20 Change Cipher Spec
    dissect_ssl3_change_cipher_spec
    packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
    ssl_change_cipher CLIENT
      record: offset = 6, reported_length_remaining = 41
    dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
    decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 36, ssl state 0x17
    packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
    decrypt_ssl3_record: using client decoder
    decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
    dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 237 offset 11 length 3359662 bytes, remaining 47 

    dissect_ssl enter frame #11 (first time)
      conversation = 05EA68F0, ssl_session = 05EA6D14
      record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 776
    dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 23 Application Data
    decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 771, ssl state 0x17
    packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
    decrypt_ssl3_record: using client decoder
    decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
    association_find: TCP port 3204 found 00000000
    association_find: TCP port 443 found 05363358

    dissect_ssl enter frame #13 (first time)
      conversation = 05EA68F0, ssl_session = 05EA6D14
      record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 1460
      need_desegmentation: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 1460

    dissect_ssl enter frame #23 (first time)
      conversation = 05EA68F0, ssl_session = 05EA6D14
      record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 10305
    dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 23 Application Data
    decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 10300, ssl state 0x17
    packet_from_server: is from server - TRUE
    decrypt_ssl3_record: using server decoder
    decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
    association_find: TCP port 443 found 05363358

    dissect_ssl enter frame #24 (first time)
      conversation = 05EA68F0, ssl_session = 05EA6D14
      record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 30
    dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 23 Application Data
    decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 25, ssl state 0x17
    packet_from_server: is from server - TRUE
    decrypt_ssl3_record: using server decoder
    decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
    association_find: TCP port 443 found 05363358

    dissect_ssl enter frame #28 (first time)
    ssl_session_init: initializing ptr 05EA8568 size 592
      conversation = 05EA8328, ssl_session = 05EA8568
      record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 1

    dissect_ssl enter frame #9 (already visited)
      conversation = 05EA68F0, ssl_session = 00000000
      record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 41
    dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
    dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 203 offset 5 length 9339809 bytes, remaining 41 

    dissect_ssl enter frame #10 (already visited)
      conversation = 05EA68F0, ssl_session = 00000000
      record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 47
    dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 20 Change Cipher Spec
    dissect_ssl3_change_cipher_spec
      record: offset = 6, reported_length_remaining = 41
    dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
    dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 237 offset 11 length 3359662 bytes, remaining 47 

    dissect_ssl enter frame #11 (already visited)
      conversation = 05EA68F0, ssl_session = 00000000
      record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 776
    dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 23 Application Data
    association_find: TCP port 3204 found 00000000
    association_find: TCP port 443 found 05363358

    dissect_ssl enter frame #7 (already visited)
      conversation = 05EA68F0, ssl_session = 00000000
      record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 6
    dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 20 Change Cipher Spec
    dissect_ssl3_change_cipher_spec

    dissect_ssl enter frame #6 (already visited)
      conversation = 05EA68F0, ssl_session = 00000000
      record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 86
    dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
    dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 2 offset 5 length 77 bytes, remaining 86 

    dissect_ssl enter frame #4 (already visited)
      conversation = 05EA68F0, ssl_session = 00000000
      record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 240
    dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
    dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 1 offset 5 length 231 bytes, remaining 240
```

how can I get the private key? and from https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20789/ssl-decryption-in-wireshark, "To decrypt you need the private key. The server's certificate, sent as part of the initial steps of the SSL connection (the "handshake"), only contains the public key (which is not sufficient to decrypt). ", is it telling the truth ?

Comment: Yes it is telling the truth, see as certificate being 2 parts, private and public. The client encrypts its information to the server using its public part of the certificate, and only when you have the associated private key for that certificate can you decrypt the information. 

The only way you can have the private key is by owning that certificate, if anyone could get the private key then SSL/TLS would be pointless.