# SSL errors using MailChimp's API

Tags: ssl, mailchimp

I'm trying to connect with MailChimp's API, but keep getting errors:

> Error. API call to lists/list failed: SSL peer certificate or SSH
>   remote key was not OK

Then, I created a cacert.pem file and set it in the Mailchimp.php file:

```
$this->ssl_cainfo = ROOT . DS . 'cacert.pem';
```

And get this:

> Error. API call to lists/list failed: SSL certificate problem, verify
>   that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

or

> Error. API call to lists/list failed: SSL peer certificate or SSH
>   remote key was not OK

Per this page:

I tried using the http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html file for my cacert.pem file, but that gives the "not OK" error listed above.

I also tried making my own with the info provided by our host (a text file, changed extension to .pem, and pasted one and/or both chunks of data into it, making it look like this):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
adjkflsdjflkasjdflkajdflksdflsdfkj
asldfkjaadsfhjkfhdsajkfhakjdhfkjdh
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
adjkflsdjflkasjdflkajdflksdflsdfkj
asldfkjaadsfhjkfhdsajkfhakjdhfkjdh
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

or just one:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
adjkflsdjflkasjdflkajdflksdflsdfkj
asldfkjaadsfhjkfhdsajkfhakjdhfkjdh
....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

At a loss for where to go from here, what to try...etc

Using the example code from here: https://github.com/mailchimp/mcapi2-php-examples

And getting the Vendor files via composer:

```
"require": {
    "mailchimp/mailchimp": ">=2.0.0"
},
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong with your setup, I just installed the example code, grabbed the vendor files via composer: curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -d detect_unicode=Off and ran php composer.phar install.  This worked fine, and after a bit of apache fiddling I could add a new user to a mailchimp list.  What OS are you using?

Comment: @BenHitchcock - Linux

Comment: 1. I couldn't help but notice the date you posted this is about when the Heartbleed updates were being broadcast--could that be related? 2. Have you tried to make a similar SSL request to another party on the same setup?

Comment: Seth, that was my thought too, however the example code that Dave is using works fine on my machine.  Dave, I just installed it on my Mac running 10.8.  I can't help thinking that there's something funky on your server, see my answer below.  Also try installing it on a different server to see if that works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Having spoken to MailChimp, the certificate they're still (Jan 2016) using  – for compatibility reasons, they told me – is the **GTE CyberTrust Global Root** (note GTE was bought by Digicert), so you don't need to replace the entire bundle, just add or force PHP to read this certificate:

https://gte-cybertrust-global-root.digicert.com/info/index.html

(note you'll get an 'insecure connection' warning if you try and load that in Firefox, for hopefully obvious reasons – you can add an exception.)

It's in standard .crt format, which is what you need. [Guide to certificate formats](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file)

You didn't specify what the server was but here's how to add an extra one on Linux without having to replace an entire bundle etc:

On Debian/Ubuntu, certificates live in `/etc/ssl/certs/`

1. Copy and paste the signature into a new file in that directory, e.g. `mailchimp-legacy.crt`
2. run `sudo c_rehash /etc/ssl/certs` - **What's going on here:** `c_rehash` calculates a short hash of each certificate and creates a symlink from that to the original .pem or .crt file.  Basically it's a quick lookup table for openssl - openssl will perform the hash as well and look for the symlink, rather than having to have a database of certificate names or open every file in turn to find the right one.
3. check it's worked with this: `ls -lh *.0 | grep 'mailchimp-legacy.crt'`

You should see something like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Feb 13 14:17 4d654d1d.0 -> mailchimp-legacy.crt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Feb 13 14:17 c692a373.0 -> mailchimp-legacy.crt
```

**Alternatively:** On Debian, there's also a file called `/etc/ca-certificates.conf` and the exclamation mark in the line `!mozilla/GTE_CyberTrust_Global_Root.crt` indicates not to use that one.  I believe it's possible to put a copy of the certificate with that name under `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla` and run `sudo update-ca-certificates`, but it seems to me it be likely to be removed again when the package & config file are next updated.

Remember to remove any workarounds you were using - e.g. 
- old CA bundles in your certificate directory
- anywhere you override CURLOPT_CAINFO in your PHP 
- an openssl.cainfo line in your php.ini

Check your application works correctly.  I didn't need to restart PHP or my webserver, the change was instant.  Worth using `apt-get update/upgrade` to check you have the most recently certificate packages.

Here's a way to verify SSL connection (and verification) to a specific server from the command line:

```
echo GET | openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -connect us3.api.mailchimp.com:443 2>&1
```

**Monitoring:** (updated) MailChimp's v2.0 API (deprecated) has an endpoint called ['`helper/ping`'](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/helper/ping.php) which returns some text to indicate the API status - useful as an automated test of API health and that your certificates are all still working.  If you're using v3.0, they recommend using the [API Root Resource](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/root/#read-get_root) and appending `?fields=account_name` if you don't actually need to check any of the data.

Someone asked in the comments if this was related to [Heartbleed](http://heartbleed.com/). No. Heartbleed is an openssl vulnerability related to eavesdropping on data in RAM.  [Mozilla removed GTE CyberTrust](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1047011) (twice) because they wanted to [remove all 1024-bit root certificates](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=881553) - research has suggested a nation state could break a 1024-bit prime.

Comment: Updated Debian Jessie a few days ago and ran into this error `cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)` while trying to add users to MailChimp. Following this solved it for me.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this temporarily on OSX without compromising security?

Comment: Thank you, tried a few times to fix this issue on a Debian + php 5.6 setup and this worked.

Answer (score 8):

You need the older certificates:

> https://github.com/bagder/ca-bundle/blob/e9175fec5d0c4d42de24ed6d84a06d504d5e5a09/ca-bundle.crt

As defined on the page:

> http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

RSA-1024 removed

Guess Mandrill an Mailchimp use a RSA-1024 version.

That is the one you need. I had the same issue.

Comment: This also works for Microsoft's Live Connect oAuth. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Debian and other operating systems and browsers have removed 1024-bit certificates because they are no longer considered secure. But Mailchimp has not switched to a higher-security certificate yet. Therefore you will have to manually re-add the old certificate to you system.

On **debian**, the correct solution is to follow the instructions in [Alternative chain verification failure after 1024b root CAs removal](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=812708#49):

1. First, Go to [GTE CyberTrust Global Root](https://gte-cybertrust-global-root.digicert.com/info/index.html)  and copy the **Certificate:** section (include `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`. Paste it into the file
   `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GTE_CyberTrust_Global_Root.crt` with this command: `cat > /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GTE_CyberTrust_Global_Root.crt`.
2. Check that it's good with the command: `openssl x509 -in /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GTE_CyberTrust_Global_Root.crt -text -noout`
3. To enable that certificate, add this line to `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`: `mozilla/GTE_CyberTrust_Global_Root.crt`
4. Update debian's certificates: `update-ca-certificates`

Comment: My dude, thank you! This fixed my starbucks wifi issue, of all things. Might I also recommend editing step 1 with the following code to simplify the process (from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7886248/6924364) `echo | openssl s_client -connect server:port 2>&1 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GTE_CyberTrust_Global_Root.crt`

Answer (score -6):

In your AppController, when you are creating a new Mailchimp instance, you can actually pass the following options:

'ssl_verifypeer'

'ssl_verifyhost'

'ssl_cainfo'

These get mapped to Curl when Mailchimp is requesting data.

So to start with, I'd try modifying line 44 of AppController to look something like this:

```
       $this->mc = new Mailchimp('yourAPIKey', array('ssl_verifypeer' => false)); //your api key here
```

This will allow you to verify that it's the peer certificate that is causing issues.  Of course I don't recommend that you consider this a valid solution for production, it's just a troubleshooting step.

Comment: Doing that works (of course), but kind of defeats the purpose of using SSL in the first place (according to the plethora of websites that offer that as a suggestion) :(