# SSL certificate error unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, cakephp, ssl, mailchimp

This error is only present on my webserver online.  I am using a updated cacert.pem and referencing it in my `php.ini` file in my localhost server.

My question is  how this could be done on a typical web server? (by how I mean referencing the `cacert.pem` via the `php.ini`)

Alternatively is there a way I can define it within my function or *Mailchimps* API function that i am using which was installed via *composer*?

**My current function:**

```
bootstrap.php
require_once __DIR__ . '\..\..\lib\Cake\Network\Http\HttpSocket.php';
```

**Controller:**

```
//////////////////////////MAILCHIMP///////////////////////
                $Socket = new HttpSocket(array('ssl_cafile' => CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'cacert.pem',         ));
                $api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
                $list_id = "xxxxxxxxx";

                $merge_vars = array('FNAME'=>$this->request->data['Subscriber']['first_name'], 'LNAME'=>$this->request->data['Subscriber']['last_name']);

                $Mailchimp = new Mailchimp( $api_key );
                $Mailchimp_Lists = new Mailchimp_Lists( $Mailchimp );
                $subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe($list_id, array('email' => $this->request->data['Subscriber']['email']), $merge_vars);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL errors using MailChimp's API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973701/ssl-errors-using-mailchimps-api)

Answer (score 0):

**Please note this is only valid for PHP >= 5.6.0 and will work automagically**

You can use `ini_set('openssl.cafile', '/path/to/cacert');` (http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php#context.ssl.cafile) inside your code if you don't have access to modify the `php.ini` file on the server (You can read more here: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/tls-peer-verification).

If you need to check the currently set location of your cafile you can use [`openssl_get_cert_locations`](http://php.net/openssl_get_cert_locations).

**If you are using PHP < 5.6.0**

You may need to extend the [Mailchimp](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-php/src/7ac99b5ac746d5875c5c350ad7e3b83674c83ec1/src/Mailchimp.php?at=master) class:

```
class MailchimpWithTLS extends Mailchimp {
    public function __construct($apikey=null, $opts=array()) {
        // Build the Mailchimp object normally
        parent::__construct($apikey=null, $opts);

        // Set the peer verification cURL fields
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $opts['cafile']);
    }
}
```

And initialize it by passing the cafile location to the constructor as an option:

```
$Mailchimp = new MailchimpWithTLS( $api_key , array('cafile' => CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'cacert.pem'));
```

Answer (score 0):

After speaking to some friends i found out that my web server host runs cPanel which has a simple SSL certificate installer.

I cant comment on the other answer provided by Rasclatt as i didnt try it. However it sounds very comprehensive.

For those who have this issue - check if your hoster is running cPanel software - and its as simple as a few clicks.