# CURL SSL unable to get local issuer certificate Mailchimp with PHP 5.6 on IIS

Tags: php, iis, curl, mailchimp

I am trying to use the Mailchimp API Wrapper which they provide. It uses the PHP Curl extension and on my development environment (PHP, Apache and Ubuntu) everything worked fine.

Now I am trying to get it to work on the live environment which is PHP 5.6.7 on IIS 7.5. phpinfo tells me that I'm using CURL 7.40.0. Whatever I do I keep getting the same error `SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

I have had a look around lots of similar questions to try to find the answer. A common theme is to download the [CA Bundle](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) (I've tried both the  HTTP from curl.haxx.se and the HTTPS from github versions) and then either modify the code to include

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:\path\to\cacert.pem");
```

or my preferred option which is to add to the php.ini file

```
curl.cainfo="C:\path\to\cacert.pem"
```

but neither of those have fixed the problem. I have also tried the

```
ini_set('openssl.cafile', '\path\to\cacert');
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28034811/990262), and this also doesn't work.

I'm wondering if the problem could be file permissions (so I've been giving everybody read access to cacert.pem to eliminate that possibility), or if the problem has something to do with needing to escape the \ characters in PHP (so I've tried both the c:\path\to\cacert.pem and c:\path\to\cacert.pem varieties) but regardless of what I do I haven't found any combinations that will make it work, except for setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false` which I obviously don't want to do.

I'm wondering if this is the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate), the main difference being that I'm using IIS and not XAMPP.

Is there anything I'm missing - any reason why this setup won't work?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you restarting IIS after changing the php.ini?

Comment: No, but I know that the changes to the php.ini are effective because if I put in an invalid path I get a different error message about being unable to find the certificates bundle. Also the `curl_setopt` method should not require a restart of IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread has been very useful for a similar problem I encountered when trying to communicate through the Mailchimp API using Windows Azure. I finally got it to work using the following steps:

**1. Download & modify cacert.pem**

I've downloaded cacert.pem from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem. This wasn't working for me either. This certificate does not include the correct GTE Cybertrust Global Root info so I've pasted it in:

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>   MIICWjCCAcMCAgGlMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAMHUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRgwFgYD
>   VQQKEw9HVEUgQ29ycG9yYXRpb24xJzAlBgNVBAsTHkdURSBDeWJlclRydXN0IFNv
>   bHV0aW9ucywgSW5jLjEjMCEGA1UEAxMaR1RFIEN5YmVyVHJ1c3QgR2xvYmFsIFJv
>   b3QwHhcNOTgwODEzMDAyOTAwWhcNMTgwODEzMjM1OTAwWjB1MQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
>   UzEYMBYGA1UEChMPR1RFIENvcnBvcmF0aW9uMScwJQYDVQQLEx5HVEUgQ3liZXJU
>   cnVzdCBTb2x1dGlvbnMsIEluYy4xIzAhBgNVBAMTGkdURSBDeWJlclRydXN0IEds
>   b2JhbCBSb290MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCVD6C28FCc6HrH
>   iM3dFw4usJTQGz0O9pTAipTHBsiQl8i4ZBp6fmw8U+E3KHNgf7KXUwefU/ltWJTS
>   r41tiGeA5u2ylc9yMcqlHHK6XALnZELn+aks1joNrI1CqiQBOeacPwGFVw1Yh0X4
>   04Wqk2kmhXBIgD8SFcd5tB8FLztimQIDAQABMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4GBAG3r
>   GwnpXtlR22ciYaQqPEh346B8pt5zohQDhT37qw4wxYMWM4ETCJ57NE7fQMh017l9
>   3PR2VX2bY1QY6fDq81yx2YtCHrnAlU66+tXifPVoYb+O7AWXX1uw16OFNMQkpw0P
>   lZPvy5TYnh+dXIVtx6quTx8itc2VrbqnzPmrC3p/
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----

**2. Upload the certificate**

E.g. in "D:\home\site\cacert.pem" - as long as you remember the path

**3. Change the system configuration setting for curl.cainfo**

This info is from a document by Microsoft:

> 1. Add an App Setting to your Web App with the key PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR and value d:\home\site\ini
> 2. Create an settings.ini file using Kudu Console (http://[site-name].scm.azurewebsite.net) in the d:\home\site\ini directory.
> 3. Add configuration settings to the settings.ini file using the same syntax you would use in a php.ini file.

Here we add: **curl.cainfo = "D:\home\site\cacert.pem"**

> 4. Restart your Web App to load the changes.

You can check if your custom .ini was picked up by using phpinfo() - it should show up under "Additional .ini files parsed"

This is what got it working for me on Windows Azure!

(please note I couldn't paste more than 2 links due to my lack of reputation, I just signed up)

Comment: Thanks for those detailed instructions. I am no longer involved in the project that required this but if I ever run into this problem again I'll know where to come to look for a solution!

Comment: No problem! I also added it for anyone who will find this through Google, as I did :-)

Answer (score 1):

The certificate MailChimp are currently still using (for compatibility reasons they told me) is the **GTE CyberTrust Global Root** (note GTE was bought by Digicert), so you don't need to replace the entire bundle, just add or force PHP to read this certificate:

https://gte-cybertrust-global-root.digicert.com/info/index.html

Unfortunately I only use Linux so I can't give you any help with IIS.