# Erlang SSL server stops accepting connections

Tags: ssl, erlang

1. Setup :

   - Erlang cluster with two Erlang nodes, different names, identical SSL setup (certificates, keys, authority)
   - the two nodes are listening for connections on the same port
   - the accept scheme is simple and doesn't have an acceptor pool in front : `ListenSocket = ssl:listen()` when the app starts -> then, in the children, I do `AcceptSock = ssl:transport_accept(ListenSocket)` + `ssl:ssl_accept(AcceptSock)` + `mysup:start_child()` which will start a new gen_server to listen on ListenSocket (in the gen_server `init()` I have timeout == 0, btw - to make the gen_server receive a timeout message which will be handled with `handle_info(timeout...)` which does the accept scheme above).
2. Expected behavior :

   - I expect all of this to work all the time :)
3. Observed behavior :

   - from time to time, one or both servers stop accepting ssl connections **from the iOS apps**. telnet to that port works - and it even passes transport_accept().
   - from the iOS app, I get a "SSLHandshake failed, error -9806" and it doesn't look like transport_accept() was successful (I have error logging before and after that line and I do not see any error messages printed in the log - theoretically, it looked like the iOS app is not trying to connect to that port, but it did try, because it says SSLHandshake failed).
   - I followed [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457408/openssl-command-to-check-if-a-server-is-presenting-a-certificate) - and got the followings :

     ```
     openssl s_client -connect myserver:4321 -servername myserver -ssl3 -tls1 -prexit
     CONNECTED(00000003)
     write:errno=60
     ---
     no peer certificate available
     ---
     No client certificate CA names sent
     ---
     SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
     ---
     New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
     Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
     Compression: NONE
     Expansion: NONE
     SSL-Session:
         Protocol  : TLSv1
         Cipher    : 0000
         Session-ID: 
         Session-ID-ctx: 
         Master-Key: 
         Key-Arg   : None
         Start Time: 1460057622
         Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
         Verify return code: 0 (ok)
     ---
     ```
   - same command executed with the second server (that is still accepting connections) returned a lot more infos and doesn't time out.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `-ssl3 -tls1` makes no sense because the first tries to enforce SSL 3.0 and the second TLS 1.+ which means only one of the options should be used. Also combining `-servername` with `-ssl3` will not work because servername needs SNI extension which is not available with SSL 3.0

Comment: I tried all the combinations, but this is the only combination that actually returns something, the rest of them timeout.

Comment: The output from the openssl command is the same as what I get when I try it with a server that immediately closes the connection (`nc -l 4321 </dev/null`). Perhaps the Erlang process crashes after transport accept but before doing the TLS handshake?

Comment: In my code I have :
 `lager:info("Listening: ~p:~p ~n", [?FILE, ?LINE]),
  {ok, AcceptSock} = ssl:transport_accept(LSock),
  lager:info("got new socket. Before ssl_accept"),`
 
When I do telnet - I see the "Listening ..." message everytime I telnet to that port (because it spawns a new child to listen for an incoming connection). When I use my app, absolutely NO message are prinded on the console.