# Get complete certificate chain including the root certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl

How do I get complete certificate chain for a server? Though some claim [one should be able to do just that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885785/using-openssl-to-get-the-certificate-from-a-server) with `openssl s_client -showcerts`, it turns not always to be the case.

```
echo | openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs -connect www.ssllabs.com:443 \
                        -showcerts | grep -B2 BEGIN
depth=3 C = SE, O = AddTrust AB, OU = AddTrust External TTP Network, CN = AddTrust External CA Root
verify return:1
depth=2 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = GB, ST = Greater Manchester, L = Salford, O = COMODO CA Limited, CN = COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = www.ssllabs.com
verify return:1
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=www.ssllabs.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
--
 1 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
--
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
DONE
```

Here we have three certificates our of four. All except of the `AddTrust External CA Root` certificate. (Possibly because it is not included into the certificate bundle. And not like this is required. And yes, I can find the missing one at `/etc/ssl/certs`)

How do I get all certificates for a server in a fully automatic fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the chain including the builtin trusted root certificate inside the verify_callback (see [SSL_CTX_set_verify](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html). With a small Perl program you can dump the chain like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::SSL;

IO::Socket::SSL->new(
    PeerHost => 'www.google.com:443',
    SSL_verify_callback => sub {
        my $cert = $_[4];
        my $subject = Net::SSLeay::X509_NAME_oneline(Net::SSLeay::X509_get_subject_name($cert));
        my $issuer  = Net::SSLeay::X509_NAME_oneline(Net::SSLeay::X509_get_issuer_name($cert));
        print "# $subject (issuer=$issuer)\n";
        print Net::SSLeay::PEM_get_string_X509($cert),"\n";
        return 1;
    }
) or die $SSL_ERROR||$!;
```

Answer (score 3):

Meta: I tried to answer this in superuser but you deleted it. Fortunately when I found this copy most of my work was still sitting in a scratch notepad I hadn't closed, otherwise I wouldn't have been willing to do the research work twice.

`s_client -showcerts` shows the certs **sent** by the server; according to the RFCs, this *should* be a valid chain in upward order *except* that the root MAY (in RFC2119 definition i.e. allowed but not particularly recommended) be omitted. However, not all servers are configured correctly, and some may send extra, missing, and/or out-of-order certs. Also depending on the CA used there may be more than one valid chain but the server can only send one. `openssl` currently will use only the chain sent, but this will change soon in 1.0.2, and other reliers already sometimes find a different chain than the one sent.

**openssl:** if the received chain is complete up to and *maybe* including a root which is in the truststore used (whose default location depends on system or build, and in any case can always be overridden) then openssl client will validate it as okay -- unless it is expired, or revoked and that info is available which usually it isn't. In that case you can write a client program that connects after setting a **cert-verify callback** function that outputs the full certs as processed by the validation loop, or other info from them you want, as opposed to `s_client` which uses a callback that logs (only) the subject name in the `depth=n` lines, which you can see in your example includes all 4 certs in the chain here. openssl is opensource, so a client program that does things mostly like s_client could be a modified copy of s_client (in this case specifically s_cb.c).

**Java** can also do this and is a good bit shorter to write, but requires Java be installed. If the received chain validates against an *anchor* in the truststore used (which defaults to a set of public roots but can be modified or overridden, and can have non-root anchors) you similarly can write a program (maybe 20 lines) to connect using a **HandshakeCompletedListener** which dumps the info from `event.getPeerCertificates()`. However if the chain doesn't validate, Java aborts the handshake with an exception and you get no certs at all, unlike the openssl case where you might get partial information before the error occurs -- plus openssl's checking, at least by default, isn't quite as strict anyway.

UPDATE: for completeness, in Java 7+, commandline `keytool -printcert -sslserver` displays the chain sent, in a rather cluttered format.

Among the **browsers** I can easily check, Firefox and Chrome on Windows (at least) can write out the chain they found and validated. ISTR but can't easily retest the Firefox error/exception dialog can also do this for a chain that fails to validate and may be incomplete. These are not automatic as-is, but I've seen ads for numerous "simulate GUI user input" tools that apparently could drive them as desired.

Comment: Hey! Sorry about nuking my other question!