# CA Certificate for aptitude Repositories

Tags: linux, artifactory, apt, ca

I am working on an embedded Linux IoT device that utilizes the aptitude interface for doing its package downloads. The packages are stored in a Debian-type Artifactory repository. This is all fairly straightforward, and Artifactory even gives you a handy guide for what deb line to add to your sources.list. Where I'm getting stuck is when calling the normal `apt get update`, it will fail for the CA certificate:

`error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: none CApath:`

My understanding is that I need to store a .pem file *somewhere*, but I am not sure where that comes from (or even what to appropriately Google here). Is this something that is generated by Artifactory, or generated on the client device itself?

Is this perhaps what I'm looking for?

[Using openssl to get the certificate from a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885785/using-openssl-to-get-the-certificate-from-a-server)