# JMeter Plugin Manager installation issue

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

While associating J-Meter plugin jar file in lib/ext folder of J-Meter Setup,I am getting SSL certificate error after clicking 'Plugin manager' from 'Options' Menu.Could you please assist me for the same?

Thanks 
Amitenter image descri[image]ption here

[image]

Comment: Try using the updated JMeter version and check once again!

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you're behind the [corporate proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) which uses an [SSL certificate](https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl-information-center/what-is-an-ssl-certificate/) for securing the traffic between itself and clients.

Java uses [`cacerts` file](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.1.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.71.doc/security-component/keytoolDocs/cacertsfile.html) to check the validity of the SSL certificates and you're getting this error because the certificate is not known to Java.

The solution would be obtaining the certificate from the proxy server (it can be done using either [OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885785/using-openssl-to-get-the-certificate-from-a-server) or just a web browser) and [adding it to the Java cacerts](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO4085.html)

You can also try downloading [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html), it might be enough to resolve your issue.

More information:

- [How to Install the JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)
- [Plugins Manager Network Configuration](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerNetworkConfiguration/)