# Sonarqube delegate authtication to Gitlab fail

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab

- which versions are you using (SonarQube, Scanner, Plugin, and any relevant extension)

  - Sonarqube: 8.2 community, serve as https://10.92.6.200/
  - Gitlab: GitLab Community Edition [12.9.0], serve as https://10.225.96.206/
- what are you trying to achieve

  I try to delegate sonarqube authtication to Gitlab SSO.
- what have you tried so far to achieve this

  I create a Gitlab Application named sonarqube, and set callback url `https://10.92.6.200/oauth2/callback/gitlab`, grant `read_user` and `api` scope:
  [image]

  Then configure sonarqube ALM Integration with Gitlab, Force user authentication, set Server base URL to `https://10.92.6.200`, so I can see this in sonarqube login page:
  [image]

  When I click `Log in with Gitlab`, I get this:
  [image]
  sonarqube web log show:

  ```
  2020.04.14 03:30:13 WARN  web[AXFzahyz3CdktahgAAf0][o.s.s.a.AuthenticationError] Fail to callback authentication with 'gitlab'
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
          at org.sonar.auth.gitlab.GitLabIdentityProvider.callback(GitLabIdentityProvider.java:104)
          at org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter.handleOAuth2Provider(OAuth2CallbackFilter.java:98)
          at org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter.handleProvider(OAuth2CallbackFilter.java:77)
          at org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter.doFilter(OAuth2CallbackFilter.java:70)
          at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:139)
          at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:108)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
          at org.sonar.server.platform.web.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:88)
          at org.sonar.server.platform.web.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:72)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
          at org.sonar.server.platform.web.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:76)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
          at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:76)
          at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:48)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
          at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:58)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
          at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:66)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
          at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:62)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
          at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
          at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
          at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
          at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
          at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
          at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
          at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
          at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
          at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
          at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
  Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
          at com.github.scribejava.core.httpclient.jdk.JDKHttpClient.prepareConnectionForBodyAndGetOutputStream(JDKHttpClient.java:269)
          at com.github.scribejava.core.httpclient.jdk.JDKHttpClient.addBody(JDKHttpClient.java:195)
          at com.github.scribejava.core.httpclient.jdk.JDKHttpClient.access$100(JDKHttpClient.java:26)
          at com.github.scribejava.core.httpclient.jdk.JDKHttpClient$BodyType$1.setBody(JDKHttpClient.java:147)
          at com.github.scribejava.core.httpclient.jdk.JDKHttpClient.doExecute(JDKHttpClient.java:129)
          at com.github.scribejava.core.httpclient.jdk.JDKHttpClient.execute(JDKHttpClient.java:95)
          at com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuthService.execute(OAuthService.java:114)
          at com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth20Service.sendAccessTokenRequestSync(OAuth20Service.java:46)
          at com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth20Service.getAccessToken(OAuth20Service.java:97)
          at com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth20Service.getAccessToken(OAuth20Service.java:92)
          at org.sonar.auth.gitlab.GitLabIdentityProvider.onCallback(GitLabIdentityProvider.java:115)
          at org.sonar.auth.gitlab.GitLabIdentityProvider.callback(GitLabIdentityProvider.java:102)
          ... 47 common frames omitted
  Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
          at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
          ... 75 common frames omitted
  Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
          at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
          ... 81 common frames omitted
  ```

Is there someone can help me, I would be so appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant error is

```
PKIX path building failed:    
  sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
  unable to find valid certification path to requested targe
```

This is typical of a java application (here Sonar) which does not have the proper certificate (one needed by GitLab) in its keystore.

You can use [openssl to get the GitLab server certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7886248/6309)

You can then [add it to the java keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27928213/6309) (java used to run Sonar)

Comment: I did as you tips, then get error like `No subject alternative names present`. I guess gitlab self signed cert file miss some must-have field for sonar. So I sign a cert by my self, then it works. Thank you!

Comment: @Libraco, can you share your solution? We have the same issue, thanks.