# paho-mqtt-python publish single with TLS ca_certs from server

Tags: python, ssl, mqtt, paho

I'm trying to connect to "mqtts://broker.emqx.io:8883" using paho mqtt but getting the invalid certificate error.

```
tls = { 'ca_certs': "certificate.pem", 'insecure': False, 'tls_version': ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT }
publish.single( topic="testtopic\", payload=payload, hostname="broker.emqx.io", auth={}, port=8883, tls=tls, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311 )
```

I don't want it to be insecure and want to get the certificate from the server instead of providing a certificate file manually. It would be a great help if someone could guide me in a right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The `ca_certs` file should not come from the server, it's suppose to contain the certs for the Certificate Authority chain that signed the certificate used by the broker.

So in this case it should hold<sup>1</sup> the certificate chain from:

- Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
- USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
- AAA Certificate Services

You need to provide the full chain or a file containing all the trusted public CA certs.

<sup>1</sup> found with openssl s_client see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885785/using-openssl-to-get-the-certificate-from-a-server)