# Java URIBuilder are in unnamed module of loader 'app'

Tags: java, get, uri

I woudlike to execute GET request :

```
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL_SECURED_BY_BASIC_AUTHENTICATION);
    URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(request.getURI())
            .addParameter("code", "001")
            .addParameter("name", "AAA")
           

    String auth = user + ":" + mdp;

    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(
            auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));

    String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);

    request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute((HttpUriRequest) uriBuilder);

    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

When I try to catch my HTTPResponse `client.execute((HttpUriRequest) uriBuilder);`
I have this error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder cannot be cast to class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest (org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder and org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing the error because you are trying to cast an instance of `URIBuilder` to `HttpUriRequest`.

You need to create an appropriate [`HttpUriRequest`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.1/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest.html) implementation in order to execute your HTTP request.

In your use case I suppose it should looks like this:

```java
    URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(URL_SECURED_BY_BASIC_AUTHENTICATION)
            .addParameter("code", "001")
            .addParameter("name", "AAA");

    URI uri = uriBuilder.build();  
           
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);

    String auth = user + ":" + mdp;

    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(
            auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));

    String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);

    request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

It seems for your comment that you are trying to connect to a site using SSL: the problem is that your Java code does not trust the server.

You need to configure a valid certificate chain and instruct your code to use it in order to solve the problem.

Apache Client does not rely on the standard JSSE mechanism for this purpose. Instead, you need to configure a `SSLContext` with an appropriate `TrustManager`. Please, see the following code (the first part is derived from [this extraordinary documentation fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#java) in the Android developer site):

```java
// Load your server certificate
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
  new FileInputStream("server.crt")
);

Certificate certificate;
try {
  certificate = cf.generateCertificate(input);
} finally {
  input.close();
}

// Create an in-memory KeyStore containing the server certificate
// It is required in order to configure the TrustManager
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType(); // JKS
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("cert", certificate);

// Create a TrustManager that trusts the server certificates in the KeyStore
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
  TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()
);
trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

// Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);

// Now, the actual Apache Client part

//Create a SSLConnectionSocketFactory and pass it the above created SSLContext
SSLConnectionSocketFactory factory = 
  new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new NoopHostnameVerifier()
);

//Create the actual HttpClient
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients
  .custom()
  .setSSLSocketFactory(factory)
  .build()
;

// Use this client to perform your HTTP invocation

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

You can obtain the server certificate from your browser or with tools like `openssl`. Please, see this great [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885785/using-openssl-to-get-the-certificate-from-a-server).

Comment: thanks for your answer ! I have this error now : `PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Comment: You are welcome. The problem seems related with your server SSL certificate. Please, see the updated answer.

Comment: @Software14 Did it work? Were you able to test the proposed solution?

Comment: @jccamparneo yes it's works, forget to accept your answer thanks !

Comment: You are welcome. Please, do not worry. I am happy to hear that it worked fine.