# The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot with SendGrid in Docker

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, sendgrid, .net-5

I am using SendGrid to send emails .net5 windows service, it works as expected when I run the application locally from Visual Studio. But it gives an exception on `SendEmailAsync` when I run the application in Docker.

**Exception:**

> The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate
> chain: UntrustedRoot

```
List<Personalization> personalizations = new List<Personalization>();
Personalization personalization = new Personalization();

personalization.From = new EmailAddress(emailDetails.SenderMailID);
personalization.Tos = GetRecipientsList(emailDetails.RecipientMailID);
personalization.Subject = emailDetails.Subject;
personalizations.Add(personalization);
var msg = new SendGridMessage
{
    From = new EmailAddress(emailDetails.SenderMailID),
    Subject = emailDetails.Subject
};
msg.AddContent(MimeType.Html, emailDetails.Message);
msg.Personalizations = personalizations;
var sendGridClient = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
var sendGridResponse = await sendGridClient.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

**Docker file:**

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/service/MyWindowsService/MyWindowsService.csproj", "src/service/MyWindowsService/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/service/MyWindowsService/MyWindowsService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/service/MyWindowsService"
RUN dotnet build "MyWindowsService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyWindowsService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyWindowsService.dll"]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears the issue here is an untrusted certificate. It might happen when a certificate is self-signed or with a non-public CA root, for example.

In this case, you can copy the certificate or CA to the specified path "/etc/ssl/certs/" of your base/final docker stage.

For example, in the second line of your docker file:

> COPY ./server-certificate.pem /etc/ssl/certs/server-certificate.pem

The previous way will show you if that is your problem. Assuming that is the solution I advise you to not copy directly the certificate in your docker file. In a production environment you should do it as a Secret in case of you are using Kubernetes or with docker-compose volumes, for example.

Edit:
To obtain the certificate you need to trust and place it on the same path as your Dockerfile.
Then edit your dockerfile as follow:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 AS base
COPY ./server-certificate.pem /etc/ssl/certs/server-certificate.pem
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/service/MyWindowsService/MyWindowsService.csproj", "src/service/MyWindowsService/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/service/MyWindowsService/MyWindowsService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/service/MyWindowsService"
RUN dotnet build "MyWindowsService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyWindowsService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyWindowsService.dll"]
```

Comment: I have added the line `COPY ./server-certificate.pem /etc/ssl/certs/server-certificate.pem` in the DockerFile but `RUN dotnet build "FXPayments.Service.FxCloudEmailService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build` line, but its giving the same exception. Di I need to do anything else?

Comment: If the COPY command ran well your docker container should be able to trust in the certificate or CA you added to the path **/etc/ssl/certs** . I recommend you to check if your container can establish a secure connection with the server your application is trying to connect. It can be done thought _bash_ from your running docker container and/or verifying if the certificate you copied is on the expected path.

Comment: what will be my certificate name? also I cannot find file on the path `/etc/ssl/certs`

Comment: Will be the same of you named at COPY command (e.g. server-certificate.pem). In the command example you need to have the right certificate from the server that you want to connect at the same level of your Dockerfile. Replace the name server-certificate.pem as you want.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t get this comment **In the command example you need to have the right certificate from the server that you want to connect at the same level of your Dockerfile**.

Comment: I tried with `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0 AS base
COPY ./server-certificate.pem /etc/ssl/certs/server-certificate.pem
WORKDIR /app` but it gives error Docker command failed with exit code 1.. your solution is not working at all.

Comment: how to get server-certificate.pem file?

Comment: The COPY command must work properly if the cert name and path matches between the instruction and the local file. BTW to get a PEM from a certificate there are many ways, look for openssl CLI or take a look at the follow link (I have not tried it with smtp servers) https://www.checktls.com/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885785/using-openssl-to-get-the-certificate-from-a-server

Comment: I don’t even know how to generate certificate