# Github authentication extension VSCode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I was trying to commit something to github repo using VSCode and I was told that
"extension github wants to sign in using github", when I allowed it I was redirected to a page with some link which I could copy in VScode to login.

[image: https://i.ibb.co/KrFHZXs/Screenshot-from-2021-12-30-12-10-09.png]

But when I did so it gives me this error:

> ```
> Sign in failed: FetchError: request to
> https://vscode-auth.github.com/token?code=e23e730e3d1c5dc&state=717aca03-28e1-486f-bbb2-57680a149638
> failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
> ```

It has become impossible to work with GitHub due to its security restrictions.

Can someone help?

Comment: What version of VSCode, Git and OS are you using? Which extension are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If somehow the certificate from GitHub is not trusted by your Ubuntu OS, [you can get it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52553687/6309) with (as [suggested here](https://jhooq.com/2-ways-to-fix-ssl-certificate-problem-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain/)):

```
mkdir ~/git-certs

openssl s_client -showcerts github.com:443 2>/dev/null </dev/null | \
sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ~/git-certs/cert.pem

git config --global http.sslCAInfo "${HOME}/git-certs/cert.pem"
```

Then relaunch your VSCode and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and my final resolution was reinstalling it. However, that didn't solve the problem, as there were remnants left on my windows computer.

In the end, I got the problem removed by completely removing vs-code (or insider) from my computer as suggested here, meaning:

1. Uninstall by running unins.exe file found in > C: Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft\ VS Code (or insider)
2. delete the .vscode or .vscode-insiders folder found in  C: Users\your_user_name
3. Now delete code or code-insider found in >C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming

I installed vs-code again and also the github pull requests. I authenticized it using my git account, and things are back to normal. I have had already synced my setting to my account, therefore my previous working setup was back.