# Why I cannot extract my certificate chain from DigiCert pfx certificate for AWS ACM

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl, ssl-certificate, aws-certificate-manager, digicert

I'm trying to import my certificate from (DigiCert) to AWS.
Where I following the instruction from AWS ([link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-import-pfx-formatted-certificates-into-aws-certificate-manager-using-openssl/)) to convert my pfx to pem format.

But I get empty file when I use the command

`openssl pkcs12 -in website.xyz.com.pfx -cacerts -nokeys -chain -out ca-chain.pem`

to extract CA chain from pfx file. I just get an empty `ca-chain.pem` file.

When I try to import the certificate into ACM in AWS the shows the error `Provided certificate is not a valid self signed. Please provide either a valid self-signed certificate or certificate chain.`

According to the AWS [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate-prerequisites.html) we need certificate chain to import non-AWScertificate.

How can I get my certificate chain correctly?

My OpenSSL version is **OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021**

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specific to AWS, but an empty `ca-chain.pem` file seems to suggest that the PFX file doesn't contain the certificate chain at all. You may need to get a new PFX file that includes the chain.

If you're in a rush you can potentially copy the certificate chain from an existing public certificate that uses the same issuer. Try something like:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername www.example.com -connect www.example.com:443 </dev/null
```

Ignore the first `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` block, but copy the following certificate blocks to your `ca-chain.pem`.

See: [Using openssl to get the certificate from a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885785/using-openssl-to-get-the-certificate-from-a-server#7886248)