# How connection with JIRA using RESTAPI with java?

Tags: java, ssl, jira-rest-api

My task is to establish a connection to JIRA in java using RESTAPI. I'm facing an error with the SSL security certificate. I have tried many times and looked on google, but I didn't find any solution to my problem. Can anyone help me to fix this error?

**APOD.java**

```java
package com.jiraconnection;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class APOD {
    public final String expand;
    public final String id;
    public final String key;
    public final String self;

    public APOD(@JsonProperty("expand") String expand,
        @JsonProperty("id") String id,
        @JsonProperty("key") String key,
        @JsonProperty("self") String self) {
        this.expand = expand;
        this.id = id;
        this.key = key;
        this.self = self;

    }
}
```

**JavaHttpURLConnectionDemo.java**

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class JavaHttpURLConnectionDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Create a neat value object to hold the URL
    URL url = new URL("https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9");

    // Open a connection(?) on the URL(?) and cast the response(??)
    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Now it's "open", we can set the request method, headers etc.
    connection.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");

    // This line makes the request
    InputStream responseStream = connection.getInputStream();

    // Manually converting the response body InputStream to APOD using Jackson
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    APOD apod = mapper.readValue(responseStream, APOD.class);

    // Finally we have the response
    System.out.println(apod.expand);

   }

}
```

**Error**

```
    Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:324)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1340)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1215)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1158)
```

Comment: You are trying to reach JIRA over `https`, so you need to use a `HttpsURLConnection` here.

Comment: i added this HttpsURLConnection but also showing same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpsURLConnection` is using by default the JDK trusted certificates to validate the server certificate whether it is known and trusted. If it is present over there it won't throw a `SSLHandshakeException`

Jira has currently the following certificate chain:

[image: Jira server certificate]

You can easily verify whether your `HttpsURLConnection` has the trusted certificate by adding a breakpoint after initializing the `HttpsURLConnection` See below for an example:

[image: debug information]

So my assumption is that in your case the certificate is not present in the JDK truststore. What you can do is extract the Jira certificate, just like shown here: [Using openssl to get the certificate from a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885785/using-openssl-to-get-the-certificate-from-a-server) afterwords either import it into `cacert` file here: `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts`. But I think it will be better to provide a custom ssl configuration to your HttpsUrlConnection as it would be more maintainable in my opinion. But either options will work.

So the following code snippet is for option 2 when using custom trustore:

**Option 2**

```java
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Path trustStorePath = Paths.get("/path/to/your/truststore.jks");
        char[] trustStorePassword = "my-password".toCharArray();

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        try(InputStream inputStream = Objects.requireNonNull(Files.newInputStream(trustStorePath))) {
            trustStore.load(inputStream, trustStorePassword);
        }

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

        URL url = new URL("https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9");
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
        connection.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");

        try(InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {

            String responseBody = bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
            System.out.println(responseBody);
        }

    }

}
```

Or you can do everything inline without the custom truststore from your filesystem as shown below. In this way you have the the root ca as pem, which is `DigiCert High Assurance EV ROOT CA` and load it programatically into your in memory truststore.

**Option 3**

```java
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String atlassian = ""
                + "MIIFdzCCBP6gAwIBAgIQAgzZlKL4HKlpT4RkDXUi8TAKBggqhkjOPQQDAzBWMQsw"
                + "CQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMTAwLgYDVQQDEydEaWdp"
                + "Q2VydCBUTFMgSHlicmlkIEVDQyBTSEEzODQgMjAyMCBDQTEwHhcNMjIwNTEwMDAw"
                + "MDAwWhcNMjMwNjEwMjM1OTU5WjBuMQswCQYDVQQGEwJBVTEYMBYGA1UECBMPTmV3"
                + "IFNvdXRoIFdhbGVzMQ8wDQYDVQQHEwZTeWRuZXkxGjAYBgNVBAoTEUF0bGFzc2lh"
                + "biBQdHkgTHRkMRgwFgYDVQQDDA8qLmF0bGFzc2lhbi5jb20wWTATBgcqhkjOPQIB"
                + "BggqhkjOPQMBBwNCAAR7p4KtlAjEKMIH66rdbCXtkR5nO20hqZco8B/L+EuJ9mqJ"
                + "PT4dmaDR8OZWzlLXfqiKKhtxuPckC5dtwns4kXyAo4IDlDCCA5AwHwYDVR0jBBgw"
                + "FoAUCrwIKReMpTlteg7OM8cus+37w3owHQYDVR0OBBYEFMw8XjgJmgk4VGCBWOyG"
                + "Lr/FMrRZMCkGA1UdEQQiMCCCDyouYXRsYXNzaWFuLmNvbYINYXRsYXNzaWFuLmNv"
                + "bTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCB4AwHQYDVR0lBBYwFAYIKwYBBQUHAwEGCCsGAQUFBwMC"
                + "MIGbBgNVHR8EgZMwgZAwRqBEoEKGQGh0dHA6Ly9jcmwzLmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9E"
                + "aWdpQ2VydFRMU0h5YnJpZEVDQ1NIQTM4NDIwMjBDQTEtMS5jcmwwRqBEoEKGQGh0"
                + "dHA6Ly9jcmw0LmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9EaWdpQ2VydFRMU0h5YnJpZEVDQ1NIQTM4"
                + "NDIwMjBDQTEtMS5jcmwwPgYDVR0gBDcwNTAzBgZngQwBAgIwKTAnBggrBgEFBQcC"
                + "ARYbaHR0cDovL3d3dy5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vQ1BTMIGFBggrBgEFBQcBAQR5MHcw"
                + "JAYIKwYBBQUHMAGGGGh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbTBPBggrBgEFBQcw"
                + "AoZDaHR0cDovL2NhY2VydHMuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tL0RpZ2lDZXJ0VExTSHlicmlk"
                + "RUNDU0hBMzg0MjAyMENBMS0xLmNydDAJBgNVHRMEAjAAMIIBgQYKKwYBBAHWeQIE"
                + "AgSCAXEEggFtAWsAdwCt9776fP8QyIudPZwePhhqtGcpXc+xDCTKhYY069yCigAA"
                + "AYCt4OEbAAAEAwBIMEYCIQC37AW4L7CCrKn0+kTydWf3zn6tdkFOg/ZI3mUU4/P3"
                + "CwIhAOnIlT0eX2nzpr6+d3GReTVlVf5+coiyYsSOJWOANM2ZAHcANc8ZG7+xbFe/"
                + "D61MbULLu7YnICZR6j/hKu+oA8M71kwAAAGAreDg7wAABAMASDBGAiEAj67xO2t2"
                + "OVtwSjLdsD8RknexjRqu+Ifwp5wO/2p8a84CIQDw9OKwzRnQ4cxYPKPrIYGm5hbH"
                + "KfVwcBMmo0u0XQ2YlQB3ALNzdwfhhFD4Y4bWBancEQlKeS2xZwwLh9zwAw55NqWa"
                + "AAABgK3g4SEAAAQDAEgwRgIhAP/l3SLBl5/9RHQvd5GjApgGAne4J/XnA68l/vQp"
                + "x7jHAiEAxWnEzde1lf4a1kMuFUyc6fBUE88GVb+zC9rjv4KCDcQwCgYIKoZIzj0E"
                + "AwMDZwAwZAIwFcy1X+o/HkXrM8rFdcjBGCieA0oBeRSSifale32U36xquKPBtSvm"
                + "2g/HAZh2N3DDAjBM4zmAiD0WTA0o3Fnh03mIwP/98RqXvjiDUL/bzovejseo8eRp"
                + "FDjNl90IcJuAoGc=";

        String digicertCa = ""
                + "MIIEFzCCAv+gAwIBAgIQB/LzXIeod6967+lHmTUlvTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFADBh"
                + "MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3"
                + "d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSAwHgYDVQQDExdEaWdpQ2VydCBHbG9iYWwgUm9vdCBD"
                + "QTAeFw0yMTA0MTQwMDAwMDBaFw0zMTA0MTMyMzU5NTlaMFYxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT"
                + "MRUwEwYDVQQKEwxEaWdpQ2VydCBJbmMxMDAuBgNVBAMTJ0RpZ2lDZXJ0IFRMUyBI"
                + "eWJyaWQgRUNDIFNIQTM4NCAyMDIwIENBMTB2MBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAiA2IA"
                + "BMEbxppbmNmkKaDp1AS12+umsmxVwP/tmMZJLwYnUcu/cMEFesOxnYeJuq20ExfJ"
                + "qLSDyLiQ0cx0NTY8g3KwtdD3ImnI8YDEe0CPz2iHJlw5ifFNkU3aiYvkA8ND5b8v"
                + "c6OCAYIwggF+MBIGA1UdEwEB/wQIMAYBAf8CAQAwHQYDVR0OBBYEFAq8CCkXjKU5"
                + "bXoOzjPHLrPt+8N6MB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFAPeUDVW0Uy7ZvCj4hsbw5eyPdFVMA4G"
                + "A1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBhjAdBgNVHSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYBBQUHAwIwdgYI"
                + "KwYBBQUHAQEEajBoMCQGCCsGAQUFBzABhhhodHRwOi8vb2NzcC5kaWdpY2VydC5j"
                + "b20wQAYIKwYBBQUHMAKGNGh0dHA6Ly9jYWNlcnRzLmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9EaWdp"
                + "Q2VydEdsb2JhbFJvb3RDQS5jcnQwQgYDVR0fBDswOTA3oDWgM4YxaHR0cDovL2Ny"
                + "bDMuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tL0RpZ2lDZXJ0R2xvYmFsUm9vdENBLmNybDA9BgNVHSAE"
                + "NjA0MAsGCWCGSAGG/WwCATAHBgVngQwBATAIBgZngQwBAgEwCAYGZ4EMAQICMAgG"
                + "BmeBDAECAzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFAAOCAQEAR1mBf9QbH7Bx9phdGLqYR5iwfnYr"
                + "6v8ai6wms0KNMeZK6BnQ79oU59cUkqGS8qcuLa/7Hfb7U7CKP/zYFgrpsC62pQsY"
                + "kDUmotr2qLcy/JUjS8ZFucTP5Hzu5sn4kL1y45nDHQsFfGqXbbKrAjbYwrwsAZI/"
                + "BKOLdRHHuSm8EdCGupK8JvllyDfNJvaGEwwEqonleLHBTnm8dqMLUeTF0J5q/hos"
                + "Vq4GNiejcxwIfZMy0MJEGdqN9A57HSgDKwmKdsp33Id6rHtSJlWncg+d0ohP/rEh"
                + "xRqhqjn1VtvChMQ1H3Dau0bwhr9kAMQ+959GG50jBbl9s08PqUU643QwmA==";

        String digicertRootCa = ""
                + "MIIDrzCCApegAwIBAgIQCDvgVpBCRrGhdWrJWZHHSjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBh"
                + "MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3"
                + "d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSAwHgYDVQQDExdEaWdpQ2VydCBHbG9iYWwgUm9vdCBD"
                + "QTAeFw0wNjExMTAwMDAwMDBaFw0zMTExMTAwMDAwMDBaMGExCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVT"
                + "MRUwEwYDVQQKEwxEaWdpQ2VydCBJbmMxGTAXBgNVBAsTEHd3dy5kaWdpY2VydC5j"
                + "b20xIDAeBgNVBAMTF0RpZ2lDZXJ0IEdsb2JhbCBSb290IENBMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG"
                + "9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA4jvhEXLeqKTTo1eqUKKPC3eQyaKl7hLOllsB"
                + "CSDMAZOnTjC3U/dDxGkAV53ijSLdhwZAAIEJzs4bg7/fzTtxRuLWZscFs3YnFo97"
                + "nh6Vfe63SKMI2tavegw5BmV/Sl0fvBf4q77uKNd0f3p4mVmFaG5cIzJLv07A6Fpt"
                + "43C/dxC//AH2hdmoRBBYMql1GNXRor5H4idq9Joz+EkIYIvUX7Q6hL+hqkpMfT7P"
                + "T19sdl6gSzeRntwi5m3OFBqOasv+zbMUZBfHWymeMr/y7vrTC0LUq7dBMtoM1O/4"
                + "gdW7jVg/tRvoSSiicNoxBN33shbyTApOB6jtSj1etX+jkMOvJwIDAQABo2MwYTAO"
                + "BgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAYYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUA95QNVbR"
                + "TLtm8KPiGxvDl7I90VUwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUA95QNVbRTLtm8KPiGxvDl7I90VUw"
                + "DQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAMucN6pIExIK+t1EnE9SsPTfrgT1eXkIoyQY/Esr"
                + "hMAtudXH/vTBH1jLuG2cenTnmCmrEbXjcKChzUyImZOMkXDiqw8cvpOp/2PV5Adg"
                + "06O/nVsJ8dWO41P0jmP6P6fbtGbfYmbW0W5BjfIttep3Sp+dWOIrWcBAI+0tKIJF"
                + "PnlUkiaY4IBIqDfv8NZ5YBberOgOzW6sRBc4L0na4UU+Krk2U886UAb3LujEV0ls"
                + "YSEY1QSteDwsOoBrp+uvFRTp2InBuThs4pFsiv9kuXclVzDAGySj4dzp30d8tbQk"
                + "CAUw7C29C79Fv1C5qfPrmAESrciIxpg0X40KPMbp1ZWVbd4=";

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null);

        for (String certificateContent : Arrays.asList(atlassian, digicertCa, digicertRootCa)) {
            byte[] decodedCertificate = Base64.getDecoder().decode(certificateContent);

            try(ByteArrayInputStream certificateAsInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedCertificate);
                BufferedInputStream bufferedCertificateStream = new BufferedInputStream(certificateAsInputStream)) {

                CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                Certificate certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(bufferedCertificateStream);
                trustStore.setCertificateEntry(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), certificate);
            }
        }

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

        URL url = new URL("https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9");
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
        connection.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");

        try(InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {

            String responseBody = bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
            System.out.println(responseBody);
        }
    }

}
```

Last resort would be disable the certificate validation, but I would not recommend that. Below is an example for that:

**Option 4**

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509ExtendedTrustManager;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        X509ExtendedTrustManager unsafeTrustManager = new X509ExtendedTrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) {}

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) {}

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) {}

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) {}

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) {}

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) {}

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
        };

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{ unsafeTrustManager }, null);
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

        URL url = new URL("https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/latest/issue/JRA-9");
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
        connection.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");

        try(InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)) {

            String responseBody = bufferedReader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
            System.out.println(responseBody);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Hakan54 but i don't have access of adminstrator in my pc that reason i can't add ssl certificate in JDK

Comment: Than you can try option 3. please let me know if that works for you

Comment: I have tried option 3 also but it is not working showing same error

Comment: It seems like they updated their server certificate, so the example of option 3 was indeed not working anymore. I have updated the answer. Can you retry option 3? And if it still does not work you can put their new certificate over there. And I have added option 4 as a last resort. Please let me know wether it works now for you.

Comment: Thanks @Hakan54 option 4 is working fine!

Comment: please vote to  myquestion