# How to skip certificate verification in poetry?

Tags: python, ssl, python-poetry

I'm trying to add a new package using `poetry add`, but it always comes with this error:

`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.140.240.64', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v4/projects/118/packages/pypi/files/47f05b39ebe470235b70724fb049985ea75fad6c1a5007ad3462f3d430da338b/tg_client-0.1.10-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))`

Who knows how to skip this verification?

**Updated:**

I try to add a package from private repository:

```
[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "my_package"
url = "https://..."
secondary = true
```

Maybe that is why the solution `poetry config certificates.my_package.cert false` doesn't work.

Comment: I checked and indeed the indicated solution is specific to the TLS / HTTPS connection, so that's not it. What I'm slightly curious about is the ".source" part, but maybe that's just me; I'm a security / TLS expert, not a poetry expert :|

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR

For every host that you see in error message, add a new fake repository and disable verification for it.

---

An relevant discussion on topic: https://github.com/orgs/python-poetry/discussions/6681

If you're doing this globally:

- Add repo using `poetry source add XYZ...` or by editing `config.toml`.
- Disable cert check using `poetry config certificates.XYZ.cert false` or by editing `auth.toml`

It might be possible to do the same for your specific project (`pyproject.toml`) instead of globally (`config.toml` and `auth.toml`). [See poetry docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#package-sources).

---

E.g.

1. For me it started with `host='pypi.org'`:

`HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/0b/fc/8781442def77b0aa22f63f266d4dadd486ebc0c5371d6290caf4320da4b7/setuptools-67.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]`

2. This was worked around by asking poetry to ignore cert verification for `PyPI` (not `pypi`). Using

```bash
$ poetry config certificates.PyPI.cert false
```

3. Then I got same error for `files.pythonhosted.org`.

```bash
$ poetry source add fpho https://files.pythonhosted.org
$ poetry config certificates.fpho.cert false
```

Final environment:

```bash
$ 
$ export PYTHONWARNINGS="ignore:Unverified HTTPS request"
$ 
$ cat /home/kash/.config/pypoetry/config.toml 
[repositories]

[repositories.fpho]
url = "https://files.pythonhosted.org"

[repositories.my_host_240_64]
url = "10.140.240.64"

$ 
$ cat /home/kash/.config/pypoetry/auth.toml 

# apparently the brain-trust at poetry call pypi.org repo "PyPI",
# not pypi. And provide no apparent way to list the "default" repos.
[certificates.PyPI]
cert = false

[certificates.fpho]
cert = false

[certificates.my_host_240_64]
cert = false

$
$ poetry add <your package>
$
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the answer of @Kashyap I could fix this problem.
Run the following commands:

```bash
  poetry source add fpho https://files.pythonhosted.org
  poetry config certificates.fpho.cert false
  poetry source add pypi
  poetry config certificates.PyPI.cert false
  poetry config certificates.pypi.cert false
```

I did not need to adjust the pyproject.toml.

Poetry (version 1.6.1)

Python 3.9.0

Answer (score 2):

https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#certificates:

> The value of certificates.< repository >.cert can be set to false if certificate verification is required to be skipped. This is useful for cases where a package source with self-signed certificates are used.

```
poetry config certificates.foo.cert false
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I updated the question.

Comment: your example in the question shows that you are setting the .cert to false *for the package* but the docs says that you need to add "secondary" source, set the cert to false for that *source* and add the package then from that *source*  - If that does not work, try playing with CURL_CA_BUNDLE and DEFAULT_CA_BUNDLE ..

Answer (score 1):

I found 2 working solutions:

1. Use poetry version<=1.0.9 and use `CURL_CA_BUNDLE="" poetry install`;
2. Extract certificate from the repository as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885785/using-openssl-to-get-the-certificate-from-a-server) then copy-paste it in the end of file with path `requests.utils.DEFAULT_CA_BUNDLE_PATH` (python).