# Failed to add value from android to remote server

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

first of all pardon for the poor english. Im quite new to android app developement. So for few weeks, i try to learn by doing tutorials. [This one particular tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-mysql-tutorial-to-perform-basic-crud-operation/#comments) is in my "I really need to understand this one" list. So i try the tutorial using remote server from free hosting, byethost. I want to use a local server like wamp,but currently my personal laptop is broken so i have to use my office laptop.

The problem im facing is, i cant add value to the server. I only change a few code in Config.java, and dbConnect.php to connect with my server.

**dbConnect.php**

```
<?php
/*
    author: Belal Khan 
    website: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net

    My Database is androiddb 
    you need to change the database name rest the things are default if you are using wamp or xampp server
    You may need to change the host user name or password if you have changed the defaults in your server
*/

//Defining Constants
define('HOST','sql106.byethost6.com ');
define('USER','#######');
define('PASS','#######');
define('DB','######');

//Connecting to Database
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
```

**Config.Java**

```
public class Config {

//Address of our scripts of the CRUD
public static final String URL_ADD="https://benerin.byethost6.com/simpcoding/crud/addEmp.php";
public static final String URL_GET_ALL = "https://benerin.byethost6.com/simpcoding/crud/getAllEmp.php";
public static final String URL_GET_EMP = "https://benerin.byethost6.com/simpcoding/crud/getEmp.php?id=";
public static final String URL_UPDATE_EMP = "https://benerin.byethost6.com/simpcoding/crud/updateEmp.php";
public static final String URL_DELETE_EMP = "https://benerin.byethost6.com/simpcoding/crud/deleteEmp.php?id=";

//Keys that will be used to send the request to php scripts
public static final String KEY_EMP_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_EMP_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_EMP_DESG = "desg";
public static final String KEY_EMP_SAL = "salary";

//JSON Tags
public static final String TAG_JSON_ARRAY="result";
public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
public static final String TAG_DESG = "desg";
public static final String TAG_SAL = "salary";

//employee id to pass with intent
public static final String EMP_ID = "emp_id";}
```

In my logcat it shows this error when pressing ADD EMPLOYEE button

```
    02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:306)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:201)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:155)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:208)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud.RequestHandler.sendPostRequest(RequestHandler.java:49)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud.MainActivity$1AddEmployee.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:78)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud.MainActivity$1AddEmployee.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:53)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
02-26 11:26:14.751 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
02-26 11:26:14.761 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:318)
02-26 11:26:14.761 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:219)
02-26 11:26:14.761 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:113)
02-26 11:26:14.761 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:525)
02-26 11:26:14.761 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
02-26 11:26:14.761 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:302)
02-26 11:26:14.761 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     ... 18 more
02-26 11:26:14.761 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
02-26 11:26:14.761 19909-19945/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     ... 24 more
```

And showing this when pressing VIEW EMPLOYEE

```
    02-26 11:28:11.301 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud V/Monotype: SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud
02-26 11:28:11.301 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud V/Monotype:     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
02-26 11:28:11.531 19909-19940/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb82454c0 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb81adca0
02-26 11:28:16.281 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud.ViewAllEmployee.showEmployee(ViewAllEmployee.java:44)
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud.ViewAllEmployee.access$100(ViewAllEmployee.java:24)
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud.ViewAllEmployee$1GetJSON.onPostExecute(ViewAllEmployee.java:85)
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud.ViewAllEmployee$1GetJSON.onPostExecute(ViewAllEmployee.java:71)
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-26 11:28:16.291 19909-19909/net.simplifiedcoding.mysqlcrud W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this ? and if i jump too far ahead in my study, what is the best start to understand this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question, regarding `CertPathValidatorException`, has been asked and has a good answer. See: [java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. Android 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122287/java-security-cert-certpathvalidatorexception-trust-anchor-for-certification-pa)

Comment: Thanks for answering, i'll look into it ^^.