# Is it possible to connect to a self signed https server without detaching from expo?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ssl, https, expo

When I try to connect to a CouchDB server via (self signed) HTTPS I get:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Non SSL works fine.

Is there any way to connect to the server via HTTPS **without** detaching from expo or getting a signed certificate?

Comment: No. Vote the issue up at https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/ssl-pinning

Comment: It now is, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70775576/4350421