# Edit AndroidManifest in un-ejected Expo App?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I've been building my RN app directly from Expo (`expo build:ios`/`expo build:android`) without ejecting, without opening the app in Xcode or Android Studio.

To get `KeyboardAwareScrollView` to work on Android I need to `Set windowSoftInputMode to adjustPan in AndroidManifest.xml.`

**Is there a way I can do this without ejecting?** (Keeping with my build-direct-from-expo workflow)

Ejecting has given me lots of errors in Xcode (fixable with a LOT of work), and I don't have *any* experience with Android development so I shudder to think what will happen when I open an ejected Android project.

Comment: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2172#issuecomment-506232455

Comment: I wrote a detailed description of how this can be achieved here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70775576/4350421

Answer (score 0):

You need to eject/detach the expo project to react-native as expo doesnt provide access to such files.
Or you can try react-native-keyboard-spacer.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to edit `AndroidManifest.xml` with [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/), followed by using [`apksigner`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner) to re-sign the apk with credentials from `expo credentials:manager`:

```sh
apktool decode myapp-original.apk
vim myapp-original/AndroidManifest.xml

apktool build myapp-original -o myapp.apk
expo credentials:manager -p android
/path/toAndroid/Sdk/build-tools/$VERSION/apksigner sign -ks @username__myapp.bak.jks myapp.apk
/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb install myapp.apk
```