# React-native Axios is working in iOS but not calling in Android

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I can't seem to get the following Axios call to work on Android.
It's not hitting the server and showing the error : [Error: Network Error].
The same code works on iOS. Do I have to do something special to enable
network requests for Android on React Native?

```
 var url = 'https://***.****.com/api/list';
 axios.get(url, 
           { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}
          ).then((response) => {
               console.log("response = ",response.data)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
              console.log("error = ", error)
          });
```

I got this error in console :

```
error = >  Error: Network Error
    at createError (index.bundle?platfor…minify=false:117949)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (index.bundle?platfor…minify=false:117857)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (index.bundle?platfor…&minify=false:32349)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (index.bundle?platfor…&minify=false:31433)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (index.bundle?platfor…&minify=false:31260)
    at index.bundle?platfor…&minify=false:31370
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (index.bundle?platfor…e&minify=false:5652)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (index.bundle?platfor…e&minify=false:5080)
    at index.bundle?platfor…e&minify=false:4793
    at MessageQueue.__guard (index.bundle?platfor…e&minify=false:5034)
```

Comment: If you are using a self-signed certificate, your app may not be trusting it. If you're using Expo, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70775576/4350421. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Both iOS and Android have worked for me in the past. A basic skeleton I use is first initiating an axios object with a helper file:

```
// test_api.js
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://***.****.com/api/list',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
});
```

...then in the file pulling data:

```
// app.js
import test_api from './test_api';

const request = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await test_api.get('/');
    console.log("response = ", response.data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error = ", error)
  };
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

it could be your error is like this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16302527/7714108

You need to get on deeper in your Error object, if you get

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: 
>       Trust anchor for certification path not found.

your error is about misconfigured server.

I have this problem on Android 6.0 - API 23 (Marsmallow) and earlier. I don't know why happen only to me from those api and earlier. I am using Expo sdk 35, and I tried with axios, fetch and XMLHttpRequest, and the error always is pretty similar "Network Error". But apart of that, for debugging I am using React Native Debugger, then my curiosity is about why when I enable Network Inspect, this error is gone.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use Axios I had the same issue but reverse it wasn't fetching the info on Ios, I went back and rewrote all of my networking functions using fetch and it worked perfectly for both save yourself the headache and just use fetch.