# Network Error on API requests on Expo Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am developing a React Native app using Expo and I recently ran into a weird issue. API requests don't work on Android devices however they're totally fine on iOS. The server I'm trying to connect to isn't localhost. I tried to use axios and fetch, both result in Network Error and the server doesn't receive a request. I also made requests to open APIs which got me the same error, so I believe the problem isn't on the server's side.

Here's the code of the request:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  timeout: 120000,
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  }
})

const res = await axiosInstance.post(`${serverHostApi}/merchant/login`, payload)
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
Network Error
- node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\normalizeHeaderName.js:8:14 in processHeader
* http://192.168.150.71:19001/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:226876:26 in handleError
- node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:575:10 in setReadyState
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:389:6 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:425:19 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:373:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I'm using Expo 38.0.0, React Native SDK 38.0.2.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution? For me, only the 1st request is always failing.

Comment: @Drunken Daddy, in my case it was a problem with ssl on the server side

Answer (score 1):

Only way that I found to resolve is downgrade the version. Or you should make sure that TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 is disabled on the server.

"axios": "0.24.0"

Comment: downgrade worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening only in the android app. It might be a case you accidently removed internet permission from your android app. Kindly check you have proper permission in the Android Manifest File.
To Check , go the YourApp/android/app/src/main and open AndroidManifest.xml
and check if you have this line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

if you don't have it , add this line inside your Manifest file like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: I am using Expo managed project so there isn't Android Manifest File. Can I somehow add "android:name" property to app.json file?

Comment: @ОльгаБелецкая see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70775576/4350421

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem.

You can use tools like SSL Labs to test the validity of your SSL certificate.

[SSL SERVER TEST](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)

I solved it with this method

Answer (score 0):

for my i include the ca bundle in my server to make it fully secure and then it can be called from android expo

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).