# Axios request getting network error on Expo

Tags: node.js, typescript, react-native, axios, expo

I have an expo mobile application running on an Android emulator and I'm trying to make a request to a local Node.js API. The request is through HTTPS protocol so I created self-signed certificates to be able to try the application.

Every time I try to make a request to the API Axios throws a Network error.

```
Network Error

Stack trace:
  http://192.168.1.35:19001/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:168381:25 in createError
  http://192.168.1.35:19001/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?  platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:168285:26 in handleError
  node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:600:10 in setReadyState
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:395:6 in __didCompleteResponse
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in 
  callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
  [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
  ...
```

I tried the following:

- Configuring the API IP on the mobile application as 10.0.2.2 as suggested in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/973#issuecomment-437221047) and didn't work.
- Testing the application without HTTPS, which works perfectly fine.
- Testing my application on an iOS device, but it has the same behaviour as the Android emulator, it works with HTTP but it does not with HTTPS.
- Accessing the HTTPS URL from the emulator's browser, which also works.

My HTTPS server is configured as follows:

```
const httpsServer = https.createServer(Certificate.getCertificate(), app);
httpsServer.listen(Environment.PORT, "0.0.0.0");
Logger.logInfo(`Listening on port ${Environment.PORT} under HTTPS protocol.`);
```

In order to create the self-signed certificates, I followed the [Heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self)

Comment: I've had the same issue in the past with self signed/non-trusted certificates in the past. My resolution was to get a trusted certificate issued. In my case I used let's encrypt.

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70775576/4350421