# Network Request Failed Expo Fetch

Tags: react-native, request, expo, fetch-api

I am currently facing an issue on the fetch function when trying to make a request to my API and retrieving the results. This hasn't happened before, only started behaving like this a couple of weeks ago. This is the error I am getting.

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
> - node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:383:16 in callTimers
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
> - node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
> * [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

This is an example of a fetch request I am running to retrieve data from the API. Making this request on Postman does give me results and as mentioned at the start, it used to give me results before as well.

```js
getButtons(token) {
        fetch('https://**.**.org/api/v1/requests/***', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'token' : this.state.token,
//                'deviceCode' : this.state.device_code,
                'qrvalue' : this.state.qr_value,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'token' : this.state.token
            })
        }).then(response => response.json().then(data =>({
            data: data,
            status: response.status
        })
        ).then(res => {
              this.setState({
                    buttons: res.data.options
              });
              this.renderButtons();
        }));
    }
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Do you have access to the API code? Are you able to access the API through postman or a similar tool? If you developed the API... are you using self-signed certificates?

Comment: I do have access to the API code. I am able to access the API through the postman after generating the token. I am not sure regarding the last question

Comment: I'll share with you two links. The first one is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512495/axios-request-getting-network-error-on-expo) that I made a week ago, the issue was with Axios library, but it may be useful the things that I tried, I cannot get a certificate yet to try the recommended solution. The second link is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/973#issuecomment-437221047) with a similar discussion. If you have any doubt, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the API had its SSL Certificate expired, which meant that requests were going on HTTP rather than HTTPS. Renewing the certificate allowed requests to go through HTTPS and this has solved the issue.