# Got the Error "SSL Error: Certificate Authority is not trusted"

Tags: react-native, asp.net-core, expo, identityserver4, react-native-webview

I have below identity server authorization endpoint to get access token. It is hosted in virtual machine(accessible only intranet).

https://productdev.co:30200/user/connect/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=https://productdev.co:30200/apm/ui/signin-callback.html&response_type=token&scope=customscope

I got below error when access using "Expo Go" inside Android Simulator after include this above URL in react-native-web-view(version: ^11.2.3).
But not getting this error, when I am accessing through browser inside Android Simulator.

```
Encountered an error loading page, Object {
"canGoBack": false,
"canGoForward": false,
"code": 3,
"description": "SSL error: The certificate authority is not trusted",
"loading": false,
"target": 3,
"title": "",
"url": "https://productdev.co:30200/user/connect/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=https://productdev.co:30200/apm/ui/signin-callback.html&response_type=token&scope=customscope" ,
}
```

Comment: Are you using a self-signed certificate? Maybe this answer can point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70775576/4350421