# react-native android fetch json stopped working

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, fetch

i am working on a react-native application for about almost a year now, and a function i wrote earlier suddenly stopped working for now reason..
here's the code snippet:

```
   var array = [];
      fetch('https://reqres.in/api/products/3') //different URL, for testing only
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((json) => {  array = json; })
              .then(() => { console.log("get Remote data DONE" + array);
```

this code worked great for some time, and now as i had to review my code it suddenly doesn't work anymore.. i get an "network request failed" error msg..

any ideas?

Comment: On Jul 13, 2021 the site got a new certificate, maybe its CA is not trusted? This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655832/fetch-in-react-native-wont-work-with-ssl-on-android?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: i've checked my api with this site: https://www.digicert.com/help/ and all certs seem to be fine..i've got no clue why this is happening now :/

Comment: check if app is allowed to access internet

Comment: the issue is within the emulator, i installed a different one and my fetch command succeed's ;) i will try to re-install the emulator, and will report back here if that solves the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it turns out that the problem was not caused by code i wrote or by any other settings related to react-native. i tried a different emulated device, which i created for testing this issue, and the code completed without any issues at all while debugging on this very device. so i tried to simply wipe my previously used virtual device (https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview. and now everything is working just fine. problem solved! :)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.