# android does not trust a certificate

Tags: android, ssl

I run `openssl s_client -connect mywishboard.com:443 | openssl x509 -noout -subject -issuer`
and i get following information about certificate (setted by client developer)

```
depth=2 C = IL, O = StartCom Ltd., OU = Secure Digital Certificate Signing, CN = StartCom Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 C = IL, O = StartCom Ltd., OU = StartCom Certification Authority, CN = StartCom Class 1 DV Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = mywishboard.com
verify return:1
subject= /CN=mywishboard.com
issuer= /C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=StartCom Certification Authority/CN=StartCom Class 1 DV Server CA
```

Then I check go to `Settings/system/trusted certificats` and see that StartCom Ltd is among them
[image]

However, when I am tring to make https requests, they throws

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: 
Trust anchor for certification path not found
```

If I use curl -I `https://mywishboard.com/xxx`, it returns

```
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl
/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

Is that certificate malformed, or I need explicitly install it to android device?(But as I understand, if certificate is signed with trusted CA issuer, than I don't need to install it, am I right?)

Comment: The CA is not StarCom is GoDaddy.. check the certificate again.

Comment: @vzamanillo just checked: `issuer= /C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=StartCom Certification Authority/CN=StartCom Class 1 DV Server CA` or i am checking in wrong way? (I use openssl s_client -connect mywishboard.com:443)

Comment: Connect simply to https URL without port and check the cert again

Comment: @vzamanillo it returns `no port defined` if i does not specify port

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection

Comment: Check it in your browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website [does not provide an intermediate certificate](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mywishboard.com&latest) that is required to complete the certificate chain. Some clients, like Android, are unable to build the complete certificate path and do not trust the certificate when this happens.

[image: SSL Labs report showing missing intermediate certificate]

If you are the site admin, the correct way to address this is to [download and supply the intermediate certificate](https://whatsmychaincert.com/?mywishboard.com) so that the complete chain is sent.

Answer (score 2):

There are two potential issues:

- The Root CA used is "Go Daddy **Root Certificate Authority** - G2 " which might not be available in your Android device.
- The server is not presenting the Intermediate CA "Go Daddy **Secure Certificate Authority** - G2". The server certificate was issued by the Intermediate CA "Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2" that was issued by the Root CA "Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2". For web servers this is not a problem as they are able to download the intermediate CA using the AIA extension from the server certificate but your Java application won't, unless you develop this functionality.