# How to set OkHttpClient for glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using Glide to load images, the issue I'm facing is that  when i run app on slow internet connection I'm getting `SocketTimeOutException`. So to solve this issue i want to use a custom `OkHttpClient` so that I can change the timeout of HttpClient this is the code i have.

```
public class MyGlideModule  implements GlideModule {
    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {

    }

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setConnectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.setReadTimeout(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory factory = new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(client);
        glide.register(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, factory);
    }
}
```

but `OkHttpUrlLoader` is not there any more in Glide API. So i was wondering how can set the OkHttpClient for Glide

Comment: Glide directly download image n set in Image view

Comment: @DixitPanchal yes but you can change the configuration like HttpClient using GlideModule

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To use OkHttpUrlLoader you need to add dependencies as the @darwin said but there is dependency issue https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/941. So you will be adding this in your dependencies

```
 compile ('com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0'){
        exclude group: 'glide-parent'
    }
```

Comment: it can not find OkHttpUrlLoader if i do this

Answer (score 55):

**since glide 4.0.0 it has changed a little bit.**

first of all `GlideModule` is deprecated and you need to use `AppGlideModule` if you are developing an application and `LibraryGlideModule` for library development. you need to use `@GlideModule` above your custom `AppGlideModule` class.

secondly there is no `register()` method in `Glide` object any more.

and finally okhttp3 will use a builder.

it'll be like below for apps:

```
    @GlideModule
    private class CustomGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

       @Override
       public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
           OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                   .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                   .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                   .build();

       OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory factory = new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(client);

           glide.getRegistry().replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, factory);
       }
   }
```

you'll need to have all these dependency with the exact versions in your app gradle file:

```
 compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1"
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    compile ('com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.0.0'){
        exclude group: 'glide-parent'
    }
```

Comment: It works for me except the missing .build() at the end of the connecttimeout line.

Comment: If you add `exclude group: 'glide-parent'`, it will write: 'Could not find method com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.11.0() for arguments [build_88p4z8p3v5idok4cebd6iktio$_run_closure3$_closure15@24e35b27] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.'

Answer (score 15):

Based on the [docs](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/int/about.html#what-if-i-want-to-depend-on-an-integration-library-but-i-want-to-register-its-modelloaders-or-other-components-myself), this is the proper up-to-date way to do it:

```
@GlideModule
@Excludes(OkHttpLibraryGlideModule::class)
class MyGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {

  override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
    registry.replace(
      GlideUrl::class.java,
      InputStream::class.java,
      OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(myOkHttpClient)
    )
  }
}
```

And you'll need all these dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.12.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

Add or upgrade `okhttp3-integration:4.4.0` version

```
implementation ('com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.4.0'){
        exclude group: 'glide-parent'
    }
```

Comment: How will `build.gradle` look like?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add okhttp3-integration dependency to your app gradile file

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.4.0@aar'
//compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'}
```

Reffer the official link [glide integration module](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Integration-Libraries)

After that u can add GlideModule with okhttp...

Comment: If you're using gradle, you can include this module simply by depending on the aar, the module will be merged in by manifest merger. There is no need to add a GlideModule by yourself.