# Glide - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, ssl, android-glide

I migrated the server from `HTTP` to `HTTPS` I have used self-signed certificate to send network requests with `HttpUrlConnection` and it worked but for image loading it is not working as I have used Glide for Image loading.

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.while loading images from **https URL** through glide library

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(currentItem.getImage_path().replace(" ", "%20"))
     .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            genericViewHolder.imageView_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_thumbnail);
            genericViewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
            genericViewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return false;
        }
    }).into(genericViewHolder.imageView_1);
```

I tried using [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-module-example-accepting-self-signed-https-certificates) link and used GlideModule but it does not seem to work. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047414/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-java-security-cert-certpathvalidatorexcepti)

Comment: It's not duplicate because it does not belong to HTTPUrlConnection, I facing this issue with Glide image loading. Can you help me out pls?

Comment: It is a duplicate because the issue is exactly the same: the server certificate isn't trusted.

Comment: We are discussing here to allow SSL certificate on Glide only and that question provides resolution of the same issue in Retrofit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is about certificate follow this link -https://stackoverflow.com/a/39032433/4741746

This will bypass certificate and allow you to enter in system

see this link also -https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-module-example-accepting-self-signed-https-certificates

Create your custom GlideModule Class,OkHttpUrlLoader class and attach to you Glide as mention in above link

You have to put

```
<meta-data
        android:name="io.futurestud.tutorials.glide.glidemodule.CustomImageSizeGlideModule"
        android:value="GlideModule" />
```

Inside  application tag of your AndroidMainifiest file https://github.com/fs-opensource/android-tutorials-glide/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Could you please tell me how this will work with existing code? And will this work in production too?

Comment: finally, the https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-module-example-accepting-self-signed-https-certificates helped. Thanks for the support

Comment: An insecure bandaid is not an answer, especially when it doesn't disclose the insecurity.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code that I copied from the answer at [Trusting all certificates with okHttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509296/trusting-all-certificates-with-okhttp/25992879#25992879) —

> Create class UnsafeOkHttpClient.java
>
> ```
> public class UnsafeOkHttpClient {
> public static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
>     try {
>         // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
>         final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
>                 new X509TrustManager() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String
> ```
>
> authType) throws CertificateException {
> }
>
> ```
>                     @Override
>                     public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String
> ```
>
> authType) throws CertificateException {
> }
>
> ```
>                     @Override
>                     public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
>                         return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
>                     }
>                 }
>         };
>
>         // Install the all-trusting trust manager
>         final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
>         sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
>
>         // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
>         final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
>
>         OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
>         builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager)trustAllCerts[0]);
>         builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
>             @Override
>             public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
>                 return true;
>             }
>         });
>
>         OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
>         return okHttpClient;
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         throw new RuntimeException(e);
>     }
> }
> }
> ```
>
> Create a class MyGlideModule.java
>
> ```
> @GlideModule
> public class MyGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
> @Override
> public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide, @NonNull Registry registry) {
>     OkHttpClient okHttpClient= UnsafeOkHttpClient.getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
>     registry.replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(okHttpClient));
> }
> }
> ```
>
> Create a class OkHttpStreamFetcher.java
>
> ```
> public class OkHttpStreamFetcher implements DataFetcher<InputStream>, okhttp3.Callback {
> private static final String TAG = "OkHttpFetcher";
> private final Call.Factory client;
> private final GlideUrl url;
> private InputStream stream;
> private ResponseBody responseBody;
> private DataCallback<? super InputStream> callback;
> private volatile Call call;
>
> // Public API.
> @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
> public OkHttpStreamFetcher(Call.Factory client, GlideUrl url) {
>     this.client = client;
>     this.url = url;
> }
>
> @Override
> public void loadData(
>         @NonNull Priority priority, @NonNull final DataCallback<? super InputStream> callback) {
>     Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder().url(url.toStringUrl());
>     for (Map.Entry<String, String> headerEntry : url.getHeaders().entrySet()) {
>         String key = headerEntry.getKey();
>         requestBuilder.addHeader(key, headerEntry.getValue());
>     }
>     Request request = requestBuilder.build();
>     this.callback = callback;
>
>     call = client.newCall(request);
>     call.enqueue(this);
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
>     if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
>         Log.d(TAG, "OkHttp failed to obtain result", e);
>     }
>
>     callback.onLoadFailed(e);
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) {
>     responseBody = response.body();
>     if (response.isSuccessful()) {
>         long contentLength = Preconditions.checkNotNull(responseBody).contentLength();
>         stream = ContentLengthInputStream.obtain(responseBody.byteStream(),
> ```
>
> contentLength);
> callback.onDataReady(stream);
> } else {
> callback.onLoadFailed(new HttpException(response.message(), response.code()));
> }
> }
>
> ```
> @Override
> public void cleanup() {
>     try {
>         if (stream != null) {
>             stream.close();
>         }
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         // Ignored
>     }
>     if (responseBody != null) {
>         responseBody.close();
>     }
>     callback = null;
> }
>
> @Override
> public void cancel() {
>     Call local = call;
>     if (local != null) {
>         local.cancel();
>     }
> }
>
> @NonNull
> @Override
> public Class<InputStream> getDataClass() {
>     return InputStream.class;
> }
>
> @NonNull
> @Override
> public DataSource getDataSource() {
>     return DataSource.REMOTE;
> }
> }
> ```
>
> Create a class OkHttpUrlLoader.java
>
> ```
> public class OkHttpUrlLoader implements ModelLoader<GlideUrl, InputStream> {
>
> private final Call.Factory client;
>
> // Public API.
> @SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
> public OkHttpUrlLoader(@NonNull Call.Factory client) {
>     this.client = client;
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean handles(@NonNull GlideUrl url) {
>     return true;
> }
>
> @Override
> public LoadData<InputStream> buildLoadData(
>         @NonNull GlideUrl model, int width, int height, @NonNull Options options) {
>     return new LoadData<>(model, new OkHttpStreamFetcher(client, model));
> }
>
> public static class Factory implements ModelLoaderFactory<GlideUrl, InputStream> {
>     private static volatile Call.Factory internalClient;
>     private final Call.Factory client;
>
>     private static Call.Factory getInternalClient() {
>         if (internalClient == null) {
>             synchronized (Factory.class) {
>                 if (internalClient == null) {
>                     internalClient = new OkHttpClient();
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         return internalClient;
>     }
>
>     public Factory() {
>         this(getInternalClient());
>     }
>
>     public Factory(@NonNull Call.Factory client) {
>         this.client = client;
>     }
>
>     @NonNull
>     @Override
>     public ModelLoader<GlideUrl, InputStream> build(MultiModelLoaderFactory multiFactory) {
>         return new OkHttpUrlLoader(client);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void teardown() {
>         // Do nothing, this instance doesn't own the client.
>     }
> }
> }
> ```
>
> Add app/build.gradle
>
> ```
> implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
> annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'
> implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.2.0")
> ```
>
> {
> exclude group: 'glide-parent'
> }
>
> In AndroidManifest.xml
>
> ```
> <application>
> <meta-data
>         android:name="Replace_your_package_name.UnsafeOkHttpClient"
>         android:value="MyGlideModule" />
> </application>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for that I just added 1. "UnsafeOkHttpClient.java" 2.MyGlideModule.java   3.app/build.gradle  4. AndroidManifest.xml meta data and its working.

Comment: That's a lot of setups hahah. But to be honest your solution is perfect. I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

Above both answer right but make sure also below dependency
Add or change okhttp3-integration:4.4.0 version

```
  implementation ('com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.4.0'){
        exclude group: 'glide-parent'
    }
```

Comment: Where to write this? I have `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'`.

Comment: in app folder's build.gradle file in dependency section

Answer (score 2):

I have try to load https Image URL inside imagview using Glide 4.x. I have apply various developer answer inside my code but I didn't get success to load images.  Finally **I found a solution to load https image URL inside imageview using Glide**. For that you have to follow below steps to attach certificate with glide request.

**Step 1**: You to import Latest glide library from glide official [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). If you enable proguard then add code inside proguard file as per mention in glide documentation.

**For Java developer**

```
dependencies { 

               implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0' 
               annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
               implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.11.0") {
                     exclude group: 'glide-parent'
               }

             }
```

**For Kotling developer**

```
dependencies { 

               implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0' 
               kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
               implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.11.0") {
                        exclude group: 'glide-parent'
               }

             }
```

**Step 2**: Once Glide Library successfully build with your project. UnsafeOkHttpClient clas. I have created this class in java but you can create this in kotlin as per your need.

```
public class OkHttpStreamFetcher implements DataFetcher<InputStream>, okhttp3.Callback {
private static final String TAG = "OkHttpFetcher";
private final Call.Factory client;
private final GlideUrl url;
private InputStream stream;
private ResponseBody responseBody;
private DataFetcher.DataCallback<? super InputStream> callback;
private volatile Call call;

// Public API.
@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
public OkHttpStreamFetcher(Call.Factory client, GlideUrl url) {
    this.client = client;
    this.url = url;
}

@Override
public void loadData(
        @NonNull Priority priority, @NonNull final DataCallback<? super InputStream> callback) {
    Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder().url(url.toStringUrl());
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> headerEntry : url.getHeaders().entrySet()) {
        String key = headerEntry.getKey();
        requestBuilder.addHeader(key, headerEntry.getValue());
    }
    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
    this.callback = callback;

    call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(this);
}

@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
    if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OkHttp failed to obtain result", e);
    }

    callback.onLoadFailed(e);
}

@Override
public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) {
    responseBody = response.body();
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        long contentLength = Preconditions.checkNotNull(responseBody).contentLength();
        stream = ContentLengthInputStream.obtain(responseBody.byteStream(), contentLength);
        callback.onDataReady(stream);
    } else {
        callback.onLoadFailed(new HttpException(response.message(), response.code()));
    }
}

@Override
public void cleanup() {
    try {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Ignored
    }
    if (responseBody != null) {
        responseBody.close();
    }
    callback = null;
}

@Override
public void cancel() {
    Call local = call;
    if (local != null) {
        local.cancel();
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Class<InputStream> getDataClass() {
    return InputStream.class;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return DataSource.REMOTE;
}  }
```

**Step 3**: Now Start create on class which extends with **AppGlideModule** and  **@GlideModule** annotation to that class.
After annotation Rebuild your project and it will create one class **GlideApp** class inside your project. This class help us to send SSL request when glide try to load https url.

**For Java Developer**

```
@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

     @Override
     public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide, @NonNull Registry registry) {
              OkHttpClient okHttpClient= UnsafeOkHttpClient.getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
              registry.replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(okHttpClient));
    }

 }
```

**For Kotlin Devloper**

```
@GlideModule
class AppGlideModule : AppGlideModule(){
           override fun registerComponents(@NonNull context: Context, @NonNull glide: Glide, @NonNull registry: Registry) {
                      val okHttpClient = UnsafeOkHttpClient.getUnsafeOkHttpClient()
                      registry.replace(GlideUrl::class.java, InputStream::class.java, OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(okHttpClient))
            }
 }
```

**Step 4**: Use the **GlideApp** such as `GlideApp.with(this).load(imgUrl).into(glide_test_iv1)`

**Summary:**
**Glide 4.0 need not have declare "GlideModule" in AndroidManifest.xml**. You just need to following steps:

1. YourAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule, you can override function applyOptions in the YourAppGlideModule class.
2. You should make project in "android studio -> build -> make project", it will generate the GlideApp class.
3. Use the GlideApp such as GlideApp.with(this).load(imgUrl).into(glide_test_iv1)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. I used this [link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-module-example-accepting-self-signed-https-certificates) and I add **'kotlin-kapt'** to **plugins** in **build.gradle** of the app so my dependencies was:

```
def glide_version = '4.15.1'
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:$glide_version"
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:$glide_version"
kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"
```

the code i used was:

```
public class UnsafeOkHttpClient {

public static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
    try {
        @SuppressLint("CustomX509TrustManager") final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    @SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }


                    @SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }


                    @Override
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                    }
                }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        //final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());


        // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
        final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();


        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true);

        builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);
        builder.hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true);


        return builder.build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

and:

```
@GlideModule
class MyGlideAppModule : AppGlideModule() {
    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {

        val client = UnsafeOkHttpClient.getUnsafeOkHttpClient()

        val factory: OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory = OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(client)

        registry.replace(
            GlideUrl::class.java,
            InputStream::class.java, factory
        )
    }
}
```

and I add this meta-data to manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="${applicationId}.network.MyGlideAppModule" android:value="AppGlideModule" />
```

I hode this be helpfull.

Answer (score -1):

**For Glide 4**

```
@GlideModule
public class MyGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide, @NonNull Registry registry) {

        //To Attach Self Signed Ssl Certificate
        /*OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, X509TrustManager)
                .build();*/

        //Unsafe Okhttp client
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient= UnsafeHttpsClient.getUnsafeOkHttpClient();

        registry.replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(okHttpClient));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer a little bit further?

Comment: i don't get why people voted this kind of incomplete answer ! `UnsafeHttpsClient.getUnsafeOkHttpClient();` the whole class is missing from the solution there is no explanation at all, you just copy pasted your code that's it .

Comment: unable to resolve OkHttpUrlLoader => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208043/how-to-set-okhttpclient-for-glide

Comment: This answer does not resolve to anything! I am surprised how people have upvoted this! A complete custom class named `UnsafeHttpsClient` is missing from the solution.

Comment: Incomplete answer -1

Comment: https://medium.com/@starryzoo/glide-https-ssl-handshake-exception-e0f22b8457f1

Comment: I wrote a similar solution as many other people did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60507560/2914140.

Comment: You Need to add these following classes 1. "UnsafeOkHttpClient.java" 2.MyGlideModule.java 3.app/build.gradle 4. AndroidManifest.xml meta data. Answer is already present on this page.