# Https Images in Glide Library for Android

Tags: android, nginx, python-imaging-library, android-glide

i have a strange Problem while using Glide as below

I cannot Load Images From *Nginx server*

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load("https://www.thehellofood.com/uploads/food_categories_images/Tandoori_Starters.jpg").into(holder.mImageView);
```

But When i use Images fro Some *Other Server* I can Load them

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load("https://ichef-1.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/11E4D/production/_92839237_001474558-1.jpg").into(holder.mImageView);
```

whats the difference between these two images do sever has any effect on Loading Images

Comment: if the file dont have read access then you cant load this.

Comment: @AvishekDas  the file has read permission

Comment: as per my knowledge this is not any Glide related issue this is server related issue.

Comment: @AvishekDas i also hope so looking for some solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon inspecting with your image link in Glide, I found the error to be because of signing the server security with Self-signed certificate *(making it HTTPS)* and server configuration. The exact error would be:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

See if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41114813/6720181