# Glide Image is not showing also getting SSLHandshakeException

Tags: android, android-glide, sslhandshakeexception

The Glide Image is not visible in the app. How can I fix this?

[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP2w9.png)

`MainActivity.java`:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imh;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imh=findViewById(R.id.img);
        Glide.with(this)
            .load("http://www.image.com/img/seatrade_supplier_logo.jpg")
            .centerInside()
            .override(100,100)
            .into(imh);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557070/glide-v4-load-https-images
this may help you

Comment: below link might help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114569/glide-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-java-security-cert-certpathvalidato

Comment: The server seems to have configuration issues. If I try to load `http://www.image.com/img/seatrade_supplier_logo.jpg` using Curl, after the redirect to `https://www.image.com/img/seatrade_supplier_logo.jpg`, Curl refuses to connect to the server ("SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"). Perhaps the server is using an unusual certificate authority. It definitely is using weak encryption.

Comment: let me o through your answers @Furqan Khan

Comment: not its showing javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7f80f3a440: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error. @FurqanKhan

Answer (score 0):

Finally this solved my issue.
 Thank you all

[Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)