# How to load image in glide with https not secure certificate

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide, androidhttpclient

i am trying to load image in glide, in localhost it will load perfectly, when i move to server it will not load how to solve this issue.

code:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(https://www.server9host.com/ocean/oceans/dashboard/nature.jpg)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.defgall)
                .error(R.drawable.defgall)
                .override(200, 200)
                .into(myHolder.onlineimage);
```

Comment: Your link is not opening in browser as well.. Your certificate is expired..

Comment: how to solve this certificate expired error i never face this kind of issue.

Comment: @ManishAhire It's the certificate issue because I have tried to load HTTP image in glide It's loaded

Comment: @ManishAhire Yes, Manish is right. Renew your certificate and everything will work as expected.

Comment: In order to trust all certificates even expired ones take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114569/glide-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-java-security-cert-certpathvalidato