# SSL error while loading image from server using kotlin

Tags: android, tls1.2, android-glide

Am using Koltin v1.3.40,in that try load images from server using glide getting SSL exception in lower end devices.meanwhile implemented TLS functionality for low end devices.After removing kotlin plugin images getting loaded properly from server.Kindly suggest to resolve the problem.

```
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException:
Failed to load resource There was 1 cause: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException(javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7d8e2a90: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744 0x746ab7e8:0x00000000)) call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE –
```

Comment: Can you add the error here?

Comment: class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
   There was 1 cause:
   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException(javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7d8e2a90: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
   error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744 0x746ab7e8:0x00000000))
    call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
  Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE

Answer (score 0):

Create a `xml` folder in `res` then create `network_security_config.xml`

So, `res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"/>
</network-security-config>
```

Then,

Go to the `manifests.xml` and add this attribute in the `<application`

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

reference: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.For API version 16 to 22 only image not getting loaded.Other devices its working fine.Implemented the above code image not loaded.

Comment: Already implemented code for TLS enabling.After added kotlin only image not getting loaded in API version below  22

Comment: maybe check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114569/glide-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-java-security-cert-certpathvalidato