# Load https url in Imageview using Glide Android OS 4(Pre lollipop version)

Tags: android, https, imageview, ssl-certificate, android-glide

I am using Glide to load images in imageview.

```
 Glide.with(getApplicationInstance()).load(imageUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.no_image).error(R.drawable.no_image).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE).into(imgView);
```

It is working for http images but not with https in Android OS 4,5.
image urls are using SSL self signed certificate. and its not loading in imageview.

From Glide Listener error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException(java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
```

I've tried to add GlideModule from https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-module-example-accepting-self-signed-https-certificates
Result : App is not showing that screen. I am not able to find the logs for this crash as its doing quick.

I have used below GlideModule but still not working for Android prelollipop version.

```
@GlideModule
public class KioskGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

@Override
public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide, @NonNull Registry registry) {
    super.registerComponents(context, glide, registry);

    OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    enableTls12OnPreLollipop(okHttpClient);

    registry.replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(okHttpClient.build()));
}

@Override
public boolean isManifestParsingEnabled() {
    return false;
}

public static OkHttpClient.Builder enableTls12OnPreLollipop(OkHttpClient.Builder client) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 22) {

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = null;
        // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore trustedKeyStore = null;
        try {
            trustedKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            trustedKeyStore.load(null, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        try {
            tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            tmf.init(trustedKeyStore);
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            sc.init(null, null, null);
            client.sslSocketFactory(new TlS12SocketFactory(), (X509TrustManager) (tmf.getTrustManagers()[0]));

            ConnectionSpec cs = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                    .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2)
                    .build();

            List<ConnectionSpec> specs = new ArrayList<>();
            specs.add(cs);
            specs.add(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS);
            specs.add(ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT);

            client.connectionSpecs(specs);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Log.e("OkHttpTLSCompat", "Error while setting TLS 1.2", exc);
        }
    }

    return client;
}
```

}

Help to solve this issue. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: make ur Uri.buildupon().scheme("https").build

Comment: It should work with `Https` also .have a listener attached to Loading call and check if you get any error or exception . Also is `imgView` is an basic `ImageView` or some custom `ImageView`

Comment: @ADM, its normal Imageview. my https url having certificate signed so its not loading.

Comment: Have you added metadata in manifest as per the answer mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41114813/5710697

Comment: @Sandy after adding meta-data, app is not redirect to that screen and crashing. m not able to fetch log as well.

Comment: can you post some sample URL so that I'll check from my end

Comment: @Sandy I have updated my question. Can u please check?

Comment: I'll check out if I get a solution I'll know u