# How to set timeout with Okhttp3 and GlideV4?

Tags: android, android-glide, okhttp

Am using glide v4 and okhttp3 integration with glide. I want to change it's timeout time. how to do that? by extending AppGlideModule or is there any other way? I have searched for proper documentation but not seen anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the timeout by creating a class, which extends `AppGlideModule` and has annotation `@GlideModule`. Then you override the method `registerComponents` and inside it, you can create a new `OkHttpClient`, which you can use to control the Glide request timeout.

First, you should add `Glide` and `OkHttp3 Glide Integration` library gradle dependencies in the build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
compile("com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.2.0") {
    exclude group: 'glide-parent'
}
```

Second, the sample code for the custom GlideAppModule class:

```
@GlideModule
public class MyGlideAppModule extends AppGlideModule {
    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory factory = new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(client);
        glide.getRegistry().replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, factory);
    }
}
```

Credits to [Amir Ziarati](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45779890/4359474) for providing the solution!

Also, refer to [this article](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-customize-glide-with-modules) about `Glide` customization with modules for more information about the differences between `Glide 3.x` and `Glide 4.x`.