# How to enable TLS 1.2 for whole application

Tags: android, ssl, kotlin

I've been reading a lot about TLS1.2 that my application needs to support but each article is about either activating on `Glide` or on `Retrofit` is there a way to activate it once and for all for the application ?

My application is using:

- `Glide`
- `Retrofit`
- `Exoplayer`

I would like to avoid duplicating the same code on the `OkHttpClient`, for every library

Articles:

- https://medium.com/@krisnavneet/how-to-solve-sslhandshakeexception-in-android-ssl23-get-server-hello-tlsv1-alert-protocol-13b457c724ef
- https://ankushg.com/posts/tls-1.2-on-android/
- [How to enable TLS 1.2 support in an Android application (running on Android 4.1 JB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943660/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-support-in-an-android-application-running-on-android-4-1)

Comment: Set your `minSdkVersion` to 21 or higher.

Comment: That's the issue I need to support 19+ otherwise yeah I would have set it higher

Comment: Then focus on using a single `OkHttpClient`, perhaps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45779890/115145 seems to show how to tie a custom `OkHttpClient` into Glide, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @CommonsWare, to enable TLS 1.2 on the libraries I've created a single `OkHttpClientBuilder` that is then use by these libraries, here is the code:

I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/yoobi/ee5c152e13944b32411d8e1f81d973ab) with the same step as you'll find below.

---

## Your clientBuilder

I've taken the custom socket from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ankushg/8c0c3144318b1c17abb228d6211ba996) and the [related article](https://ankushg.com/posts/tls-1.2-on-android/)

```kotlin
val clientBuilder by lazy {
    OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .enableTls12()
}
```

---

## Retrofit

Nothing too hard, just add `client` to the chain

```kotlin
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
    .client(clientBuilder.build())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()
```

---

## Glide

We need to add these implementation to be able to custom Glide

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.11.0'
implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.11.0'){
    exclude group: 'glide-parent'
}
```

```kotlin
@GlideModule
class CustomGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {

    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        registry.replace(
            GlideUrl::class.java,
            InputStream::class.java,
            OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(clientBuilder.build())
        )
    }

}
```

Once this is in place, you just need to call:

```kotlin
GlideApp.with(this)
    .load(URL)
    .into(image)
```

---

## Exoplayer

```
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-okhttp:2.11.4"
```

```kotlin
val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = OkHttpDataSourceFactory(
    clientBuilder.build(),
    Util.getUserAgent(context, "RecyclerView VideoPlayer")
)
```

then just use your dataSourceFactory with your mediaSource and play the video

```kotlin
val videoSource: MediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(mediaUrl))
```