# SSL cert issue while accessing wso2 endpoints through android app

Tags: wso2, ssl-certificate

I have exposed some apis in wso2 api manager 1.10.0, i am finding issue to access these api endpoints through android app. whenever tried accessing via app getting following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
05-20 16:16:31.881 20514-20641/com.accenture.mytelco W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:430)
05-20 16:16:31.881 20514-20641/com.accenture.mytelco W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:1014)
05-20 16:16:31.881 20514-20641/com.accenture.mytelco W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:955)
05-20 16:16:31.881 20514-20641/com.accenture.mytelco W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:411)
05-20 16:16:31.881 20514-20641/com.accenture.mytelco W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:343)
05-20 16:16:31.881 20514-20641/com.accenture.mytelco W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
05-20 16:16:31.881 20514-20641/com.accenture.mytelco W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
05-20 16:16:31.881 20514-20641/com.accenture.mytelco W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
05-20 16:16:31.881 20514-20641/com.accenture.mytelco W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:161)
```

Can anyone please suggest how to resolve it, please reply at the earliest.

Answer (score 0):

Did you search the internet before asking the question here. When I did a google search, I found this.
[Trust Anchor not found for Android SSL Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection)

And, there are many other posts in Stackoverflow for similar questions.