# Ignoring the CA that issued the server certificate was unknown prroblem

Tags: android

I am trying to open build a web service using unknown https link,
I am using htts the folowing code to open connection but it fails:

```
URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
```

How can I continue anyway instead of displaying the following error:

```
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:361)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:192)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:149)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:112)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:184)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:286)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:243)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.worklight.wlclient.CertificatePinningInterceptor.intercept(CertificatePinningInterceptor.java:20)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:232)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.worklight.wlclient.OkHttpInterceptor.intercept(OkHttpInterceptor.java:145)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:232)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:205)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:80)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequestSender.run(WLRequestSender.java:49)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
07-27 14:35:52.927 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:549)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:401)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:375)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:304)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178)
07-27 14:35:52.928 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:596)
07-27 14:35:52.929 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
07-27 14:35:52.929 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
07-27 14:35:52.929 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err:  ... 20 more
07-27 14:35:52.929 11424-11956/com.test.Push W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Thank you in advanced !

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection

Comment: "How can I continue anyway instead of displaying the following error" -- you don't. If you try, you will be banned from the Play Store. Tell the user that you cannot communicate with that server.

Comment: How can I check to tell the user that "you cannot communicate with that server."?
Thank you in advanced