# How can I get request url from retrofit with rx ? - Android

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android, okhttp

`MinSdkVersion` of my application is `17` and `targetSdkVersion` is `25` .In this application I am connecting to service with Rx and retrofit, this code don't work on `api 17` I can't connect to `webService`, bellow is my code :

My `RetrofitApi.java` :

```
public class RetrofitApi {
    private static PublicApi retrofit = null;

    public static PublicApi getClient(String url) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build().create(PublicApi.class);
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

My `PublicApi.java` :

```
public interface PublicApi {

    @GET("/web_service/mobile/rest")
    Observable<LastNews> lastNews(@Query("function") String function);
}
```

And  :

```
PublicApi publicApi = RetrofitApi.getClient("https://xxx.xxx.xxx/");
CompositeDisposable mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
mCompositeDisposable.add(publicApi.lastNews("getLastNews")
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(this::responseLastNews, this::errorLastNews));
private void responseLastNews(LastNews lastNewses){
}
private void errorLastNews(Throwable error) {
    Log.i("LOG", error.getMessage());
}
```

When I tested on `API 17` get me error and don't connect to server.Told me :

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Comment: Try to remove "/web_service" from baseUrl or from @GET parameter because it is taken twice. But I'm not sure that it is reason of the bug.

Comment: @ Dmitry Gorkovets.Not worked .

Comment: Probably not related to Rx. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825226/trust-anchor-not-found-for-android-ssl-connection)

Comment: How to get the request url in retrofit 2.0 with rxjava?

Comment: @Jo Jo Roid You can use [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) to watch your network requests

Comment: @  Nicolas. Do you have any sample? How can I do it ?

Comment: @Jo Jo Roid https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-log-network-traffic-with-stetho-and-chrome-developer-tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base URL `(**https**://xxx.xxx.xxx/)` is secured with `SSL`, you need to implement `SSL` connection to get it working.

Please refer [this link](https://marthinmhpakpahan.wordpress.com/2016/10/26/first-blog-post/)